# How to achieve a soft hyphen in HTML

Tags: html, text, soft-hyphen

How can I solve the problem of soft hyphens on my web pages? In text, there can be long words which I might want to line break with a hyphen, but I do not want the hyphen to show if the whole word is on the same line. I have heard of `&shy;` and of `<wbr>`.

According to comments on [this page](https://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/breaking-long-urls) `<wbr>` is a non-standard "tag soup invented by Netscape". It seems like `&shy;` [has its problems with standard compliance as well](https://www.cs.tut.fi/%7Ejkorpela/shy.html).

How can I use soft hyphens in HTML in a way that works in all browsers?

Comment: Please notice that `<wbr>` is not supposed to be a hyphen at all.

Comment: For testing browsers: https://jsfiddle.net/k2hbrjz8/2/
Either &#173; or &shy; seems to work as desired for display and copy/paste. <wbr> only selects half of word when double clicked. Search finds all in current Firefox (as of this comment date). If &#173; indexes better, use it.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

[According to QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html), `&shy;` is supported on all major browsers.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. Try searching for a word containing a soft hyphen in your browser. Most browsers treat it as two separate words, instead of symply ignoring the soft hyphen.

Comment: @gclj5 I just tested find on a `&shy;` word in Chrome v21, and it correctly ignores the soft hyphen. Not sure about IE, FF and other browsers though.

Comment: It works okay (i.e. words are searchable) in recent FF, Chrome and Safari.

Comment: But copy text with &shy; in Chrome return text with dash. Example: "uni&shy;later&shy;al." copied as "uni-­later­-al."

Comment: On some mobile devices I have tried `&shy;` does not emit a hyphen when it breaks a word. Why not?

Comment: Today we had to drop ```&shy;``` usage due to specific bugs in Webkit (affecting Safari, Safari iOS and Chrome latest versions) causing weird characters rendering with a significant number of custom fonts (both free and commercial)

Comment: I've just tested in some browsers, if the find function and copy-pasting works now. Chrome: works. Firefox: works. Edge: **only copy-pasting works**. IE11: **fails**.

Answer (score 86):

They all perform pretty well, `&#173;` edges it as Google can still index of words containing it.

- **In browsers:** `&shy;` and `&#173;` both display as expected in major browsers (even old IE!). `<wbr>` isn't supported in recent versions of IE (10 or 11) and doesn't work properly in Edge.
- **When copied and pasted from browsers:** (tested 2015) as expected for `&shy;` and `&#173;` for Chrome and Firefox on Mac, on Windows (10), it keeps the characters and pastes hard hyphens into Notepad and invisible soft hyphens into applications that support them. IE (win7) always pastes with hyphens, even in IE10, and Safari (Mac) copies in a way which pastes as hyphens in some applications (e.g. MS Word), but not others
- **Find on page** works for `&shy;` and `&#173;` on all browsers except IE which only matches exact copied-and-pasted matches (even up to IE11)
- **Search engines:** Google matches words containing `&#173;` with words typed normally. As of 2017 it appears to no longer match words containing `&shy;`. Yandex appers to be the same. Bing and Baidu seem to not match either.

---

### Test it

For up-to-date live testing, here are some examples of unique words with soft hyphens.

- `&shy;` - `confumbabbl&shy;ication&shy;ism` - confumbabbl­ication­ism

  - ..............................................................................................................confumbabbl­ication­ism
  - ..................................................................................................................confumbabbl­ication­ism

`<wbr>` - `donfounbabbl<wbr>ication<wbr>ism`. This site removes `<wbr/>` from output. Here's a [jsbin.com snippet for testing](http://jsbin.com/geyageloci/1/edit).

- `&#173;` - `eonfulbabbl&#173;ication&#173;ism` - eonfulbabbl­ication­ism

  - .................................................................................................................eonfulbabbl­ication­ism
  - ....................................................................................................................eonfulbabbl­ication­ism

Here they are with no shy hyphens (this is for copying and pasting into find-on-page testing; written in a way which won't break the search engine tests):

`ZZZconfumbabblicationismZZZdonfounbabblicationismZZZeonfulbabblicationismZZZ`

### Display across browsers

Success: displaying as a normal word, except where it should break, when it breaks and hyphenates in the specified place.

Failure: displaying unusually, or failing to break in the intended place.

- Chrome (40.0.2214.115, Mac): `&shy;` success, `<wbr>` success, `&#173;` success
- Firefox (35.0.1, Mac):  `&shy;` success, `<wbr>` success, `&#173;` success
- Safari (6.1.2, Mac):  `&shy;` success, `<wbr>` *not tested yet*, `&#173;` success
- Edge (Windows 10): `&shy;` success, `<wbr>` **fail** (break but no hyphen), `&#173;` success
- IE11 (Windows 10): `&shy;` success, `<wbr>` **fail** (no break), `&#173;` success
- IE10 (Windows 10): `&shy;` success, `<wbr>` **fail** (no break), `&#173;` success
- IE8 (Windows 7): erratic - sometimes, none of them work at all and they all just follow css `word-wrap`. Sometimes, they seem to all work. Not yet found any clear pattern as to why.
- IE7 (Windows 7): `&shy;` success, `<wbr>` success, `&#173;` success

### Copy-paste across browsers

Success: copying and pasting the whole word, unhyphenated. (tested on Mac pasting into browser search, MS Word 2011, and Sublime Text)

Failure: pasting with a hyphen, space, line break, or with junk characters.

- Chrome (40.0.2214.115, Mac): `&shy;` success, `<wbr>` success, `&#173;` success
- Firefox (35.0.1, Mac):  `&shy;` success, `<wbr>` success, `&#173;` success
- Safari (6.1.2, Mac):  `&shy;` **fail** into MS Word (pastes all as hyphens), success in other applications `<wbr>` **fail**, `&#173;` **fail** into MS Word (pastes all as hyphens), success in other applications
- IE10 (Win7): `&shy;` **fail** pastes all as hyphens, `<wbr>` **fail**, `&#173;` **fail** pastes all as hyphens
- IE8 (Win7): `&shy;` **fail** pastes all as hyphens, `<wbr>` **fail**, `&#173;` **fail** pastes all as hyphens
- IE7 (Win7): `&shy;` **fail** pastes all as hyphens, `<wbr>` **fail**, `&#173;` **fail** pastes all as hyphens

### Search engine matching

Updated in November 2017. `<wbr>` not tested because StackOverflow's CMS stripped it out.

Success: searches on the whole, non-hyphenated word find this page.

Failure: search engines only find this page on searches for the broken segments of the words, or a word with hyphens.

- Google: `&shy;` fails, `&#173;` succeeds
- Bing: `&shy;` fails, `&#173;` fails
- Baidu: `&shy;` fails, `&#173;` fails (can match fragments within longer strings but not the words on their own containing a `&#173;` or `&shy;`)
- Yandex: `&shy;` fails, `&#173;` succeeds (though it's possible it's matching a string fragment like Baidu, not 100% sure)

### Find on page across browsers

Success and failure as search engine matching.

- Chrome (40.0.2214.115, Mac): `&shy;` success, `<wbr>` success, `&#173;` success
- Firefox (35.0.1, Mac):  `&shy;` success, `<wbr>` success, `&#173;` success
- Safari (6.1.2, Mac):  `&shy;` success, `<wbr>` success, `&#173;` success
- IE10 (Win7): `&shy;` **fail** only matches when both contain shy hyphens, `<wbr>` success, `&#173;` **fail** only matches when both contain shy hyphens
- IE8 (Win7): `&shy;` **fail** only matches when both contain shy hyphens, `<wbr>` success, `&#173;` **fail** only matches when both contain shy hyphens
- IE7 (Win7): `&shy;` **fail** only matches when both contain shy hyphens, `<wbr>` success, `&#173;` **fail** only matches when both contain shy hyphens

Comment: Today, `<wbr/>` works in Firefox and Chrome. (And, to be honest, I suspect it did even in February, at least on Windows.)

Comment: I am using the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox on Windows 7, and `<wbr/>` works in both. Please notice that the `<wbr>` element **is not supposed to add a hyphen** when a break occurs. In other words, `<wbr/>` and `&shy;` [are **not** supposed to do the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29720524/282848).

Comment: Ah, looking at it, it looks like SE's CMS has removed the `<wbr/>`s from the final markup, while keeping them in the source code. Damn you SE! Will edit..

Comment: Strange, can't reproduce that 'bug'.

Comment: Is there any point in testing `&shy;` and `&#173;`? Once they reach the DOM they are *literally the same*; only in the HTML tokenizer are they at all different.

Comment: Just for further info: According to _caniuse_ IE dropped `<wbr>` support since version 8: http://caniuse.com/#feat=wbr-element
Some second testing in practice would be nice though, especially for IE 11.

Comment: So much effort for one tiny line. Great answer.

Answer (score 34):

There is an ongoing effort to [standardize hyphenation in CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#hyphenation).

Some modern browsers, notably Safari and Firefox, already support this. Here is a good and up to date [reference on browser support](http://caniuse.com/css-hyphens).

Once the CSS hyphenation gets implemented universally, that would be the best solution. In the meantime, I can recommend [Hyphenator](http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/) - a JS script that figures out how to hyphenate your text in the way most appropriate for a particular browser.

Hyphenator:

- relies on [Franklin M. Liangs hyphenation algorithm](http://www.tug.org/docs/liang/liang-thesis.pdf), commonly known from LaTeX and OpenOffice.
- uses CSS3 hyphenation where it is available,
- automatically inserts `&shy;` on most other browsers,
- supports multiple languages,
- is highly configurable,
- gracefully falls back in case javascript is not enabled.

I've used it and it works great!

Comment: I was wrong, Firefox does work but you have to include a lang type in your html tag.

Comment: The Hyphenator script seems no longer maintained, but there is a new version from the same author available here: https://github.com/mnater/Hyphenopoly

Answer (score 22):

I use `&shy;`, inserted manually where necessary.

I always find it a pity that people don’t use techniques because there is some—maybe old or strange—browser around which doesn’t handle them the way they were specified. I found that `&shy;` is working properly in both recent Internet Explorer and Firefox browsers, that should be enough. You may include a browser check telling people to use something mature or continue at their own risk if they come around with some strange browser.

Syllabification isn’t that easy and **I cannot recommend leaving it to some Javascript**. It’s a language specific topic and may need to be carefully revised by the deskman if you don’t want it to turn your text irritating. Some languages, such as German, form compound words and are likely to lead to decomposition problems. E.g. `Spargelder` (*germ.* saved money, pl.) may, by syllabification rules, be wrapped in two places (`Spar-gel-der`). However, wrapping it in the second position, turns the first part to show up as `Spargel-` (*germ.* asparagus), activating a completely misleading concept in the head of the reader and therefore shoud be avoided.

And what about the string `Wachstube`? It could either mean ‘guardroom’ (`Wach-stu-be`) or ‘tube of wax’ (`Wachs-tu-be`). You may probably find other examples in other languages as well. **You should aim to provide an environment in which the deskman can be supported in creating a well-syllabified text, proof-reading every critical word.**

Comment: The common example in English of Spar-gelder vs. Spargel-der is "re-cord" vs "rec-ord" (homographs but not homophones). The former is a verb, the latter is a noun. Algorithms are usually not smart enough for this, even in English (one of the best supported languages in IT).

Comment: I would suggest experts-exchange vs expert-sexchange

Answer (score 20):

It is very important to notice that, as of HTML5, `<wbr>` and `&shy;` **are not supposed to do the same thing**!

**Soft hyphens**

`&shy;` is a soft hyphen, i.e., U+00AD: SOFT HYPHEN. For example,

```
innehålls&shy;förteckning
```

might be rendered as

```
innehållsförteckning
```

or as

```
innehålls-
förteckning
```

As of today, soft hyphens work in Firefox, Chrome, and Internet Explorer.

**The `wbr` element**

[The `wbr` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/single-page.html#the-wbr-element) is a word-break opportunity, which will not display a hyphen if a line break occurs. For example,

```
ABCDEFG<wbr/>abcdefg
```

might be rendered as

```
ABCDEFGabcdefg
```

or as

```
ABCDEFG
abcdefg
```

As of today, this element works in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 5):

The [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) entity can be used in place of `<wbr>` tag reliably on virtually every platform.

```
&#8203;
```

Also useful is the [word joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_joiner) entity, that can be used to prohibit a break. (Insert between each character of a word, except where you want the break.)

```
&#8288;
```

With the two of these, you can do anything.

Answer (score 2):

This is a crossbrowser solution that I was looking at a little while ago that runs on the client and using jQuery:

```
(function($) { 
  $.fn.breakWords = function() { 
    this.each(function() { 
      if(this.nodeType !== 1) { return; } 

      if(this.currentStyle && typeof this.currentStyle.wordBreak === 'string') { 
        //Lazy Function Definition Pattern, Peter's Blog 
        //From http://peter.michaux.ca/article/3556 
        this.runtimeStyle.wordBreak = 'break-all'; 
      } 
      else if(document.createTreeWalker) { 

        //Faster Trim in Javascript, Flagrant Badassery 
        //http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript 

        var trim = function(str) { 
          str = str.replace(/^\s\s*/, ''); 
          var ws = /\s/, 
          i = str.length; 
          while (ws.test(str.charAt(--i))); 
          return str.slice(0, i + 1); 
        }; 

        //Lazy Function Definition Pattern, Peter's Blog 
        //From http://peter.michaux.ca/article/3556 

        //For Opera, Safari, and Firefox 
        var dWalker = document.createTreeWalker(this, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, false); 
        var node,s,c = String.fromCharCode('8203'); 
        while (dWalker.nextNode()) { 
          node = dWalker.currentNode; 
          //we need to trim String otherwise Firefox will display 
          //incorect text-indent with space characters 
          s = trim( node.nodeValue ).split('').join(c); 
          node.nodeValue = s; 
        } 
      } 
    }); 

    return this; 
  }; 
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

I used [soft hyphen unicode character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) successfully in few desktop and mobile browsers to solve the issue.

The unicode symbol is `\u00AD` and is pretty easy to insert into Python unicode string like `s = u'Языки и методы програм\u00ADми\u00ADро\u00ADва\u00ADния'`.

Other solution is to insert the unicode char itself, and the source string will look perfectly ordinary in editors like Sublime Text, Kate, Geany, etc (cursor will feel the invisible symbol though).

Hex editors of in-house tools can automate this task easily.

An easy kludge is to use rare and visible character, like `¦`, which is easy to copy and paste, and replace it on soft hyphen using, e.g. frontend script in `$(document).ready(...)`. Source code like `s = u'Языки и методы про¦гра¦м¦ми¦ро¦ва¦ния'.replace('¦', u'\u00AD')` is easier to read than `s = u'Языки и методы про\u00ADг\u00ADра\u00ADм\u00ADми\u00ADро\u00ADва\u00ADния'`.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `wbr`, so the code can be written like this:

```
<p>这里有一段很长，很长的<wbr
></wbr>文字；这里有一段</p>
```

It won't lead space between charaters, while `&shy;` won't stop spaces created by line breaks.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes web browsers seems to be more forgiving if you use the Unicode string `&#173;` rather than the `&shy;` entity.

Answer (score -1):

If you have bad luck and still has to use JSF 1, then the only solution is to use &#173;, &shy; does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Keep it simple. **A soft hyphen is just a character**. Like A or B or . You don't need a special character to include it, you can just type it (if your computer is set up for that), or copy/paste it from elsewhere.
Like here: [Soft Hyphen on unicode explorer](https://unicode-explorer.com/c/00AD)

Of course, the character you should copy is invisible, so that makes it a little difficult I guess :) But it still works. Right-click and copy.

You also don't need to render text containing a soft hyphen in any special way (like "DangerouslySetInnerHTML" with React). It is just a character; it works like it should in all relevant browsers worth any amount of salt.

As an example, in the next paragraph I will write the phrase "a really long word with soft hyphens instead of whitespace that should span at least two lines ow text no matter how big your screen is". Except I'll put in soft hyphens instead of whitespace. Here goes:

a­really­long­word­with­soft­hyphens­instead­of­whitespace­that­should­span­at­least­two­lines­of­text­no­matter­how­big­your­screen­is

Comment: I think this question predates widespread use of Unicode in text editors. In modern times, you are correct: there is no longer any need to use ASCII and HTML entities.