# How can I insert a character after every n characters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string:
*"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs."*

I want to use JavaScript (possibly with jQuery) to insert a character every *n* characters.  For example I want to call:

```
var s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs.";
var new_s = UpdateString("$",5);
// new_s should equal "The q$uick $brown$ fox $jumps$ over$ the $lazy $dogs.$"
```

The goal is to use this function to insert [&shy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226464/soft-hyphen-in-html-wbr-vs) into long strings to allow them to wrap.

Maybe someone knows of a better way?

Comment: You're better off letting the browser wrap text. Do you have long sentences like you used for your example above, or long words?

Comment: The browser won't wrap within a word, I have long words like "ThisIsAStupidLabelThatOneOfMyUsersWillTryToMakeInMyApplication"

Comment: Wouldn't a server side solution to break words into a maximum of n characters would be better?

Comment: Possibly, but a client side solution is more easily implemented for my current predicament.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

```
function chunk(str, n) {
    var ret = [];
    var i;
    var len;

    for(i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i += n) {
       ret.push(str.substr(i, n))
    }

    return ret
};

chunk("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs.", 5).join('$');
// "The q$uick $brown$ fox $jumps$ over$ the $lazy $dogs."
```

Comment: @Andy E: heh, they're optional just before a closing `}`. I don't even realize I do that anymore. It's born from a "must conserve every byte" mentality from years before js compressors became standard ;)

Comment: `String.split("")` & `Array.form()`

Comment: regex & string.split() & array.form() & slice() & map() & JSON.parse()

Comment: A word of caution for anyone relying on this answer in 2023: `substr()` is a legacy function (not fully deprecated yet) and should be avoided where possible: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

Answer (score 221):

With regex

```
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs.".replace(/(.{5})/g,"$1$")

The q$uick $brown$ fox $jumps$ over$ the $lazy $dogs.$
```

Comment: Damn it! Nice regex-fu there. BTW is the last `$` needed in the replacement string?

Comment: The last **$** in the replacement string is not needed, you can put what ever you want to put at the 5 space interval here, like **<br>** for instance.

Comment: I arrived at `"string".replace(/.{5}/g, "$&" + "<br>");`. The concatenation at the end is just to make it easier to read. `$&` in the replacement matches the matched string, so no grouping is required.

Comment: How would that work when counting from the end of the string?

Comment: Great. One important note is if the string contains line breaks, this will start counting from zero at the start of every line, since `.` doesn't match `\n` or `\r`. This is perfect for folding long lines of plaintext, but may not be desirable with web content. To include newlines in the match use `/[\s\S]{5}/g`.

Comment: @philk Regex really only works left-to-right. You can, in some cases, use replace within a loop to effectively go right-to-left: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835754/regex-reads-from-right-to-left). But this won't work if the inserted character already occurs in the string. It's much easier to adapt Crescent Fresh's answer to count backward.

Comment: Best answer, although the `$` used for the inserted character is a bit confusing.

Comment: How to only add a "-" after 3 characters and then do a break without continuing to other characters?

Comment: can someone provide same functionality using php

Answer (score 62):

> Keep it simple

```
  var str = "123456789";
  var parts = str.match(/.{1,3}/g);
  var new_value = parts.join("-"); //returns 123-456-789
```

Comment: what in case I have a ten letter number and I want to have the '-' after 3rd and 6th letter only! and NOT the 9th letter.

Comment: @Learner remove the last "-" using regex.

Comment: Can you share? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "123-456-789-0".replace(/-([^-]+)$/, '$1');
//remove last dash

Comment: Love this idea. Can this be done on the fly as well (while user is still typing)?

Comment: @JonSnow You'll need to call it in an event listener [keyup event](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_keyup.asp)

Comment: How to only add a "-" after 3 characters and then do a break without continuing to other characters?

Answer (score 8):

```
let s = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs.';
s.split('').reduce((a, e, i)=> a + e + (i % 5 === 4 ? '$' : ''), '');
```

Explain: **split('')** turns a string into an array. Now we want to turn the array back to one single string. **Reduce** is perfect in this scenario. Array's reduce function takes 3 parameters, first is the accumulator, second is the iterated element, and the third is the index. Since the array index is 0 based, to insert after 5th, we are looking at index i%5 === 4.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this code. Here is the code, based on yours, I use to add a space every 2 chars for a phone number input (keyup event) : 
~~~
$(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/ /g,"").split('').reduce((a,e,i) => a + e + (i % 2 === 1 ? ' ': ''),'').trim() );
~~~

Answer (score 3):

```
var str="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR";
function formatStr(str, n) {
   var a = [], start=0;
   while(start<str.length) {
      a.push(str.slice(start, start+n));
      start+=n;
   }
   console.log(a.join(" "));
}
formatStr(str,3);
```

Comment: Try to explain your answer

Answer (score 2):

```
function addItemEvery (str, item, every){
  for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if(!(i % (every + 1))){
      str = str.substring(0, i) + item + str.substring(i);
    }
   }
  return str.substring(1);
}
```

Result:

```
> addItemEvery("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs.", '$', 5)
> "The q$uick $brown$ fox $jumps$ over$ the $lazy $dogs."
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one of the previous answers, but I wrapped it in a function, and I gave it an "offset" parameter instead of hard coding it.

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/2712896/3480193
addCharToStringEveryXSpots(str, char, offset) {
    if ( ! char ) {
        return str;
    }
    
    let regExPattern = new RegExp('(.{' + offset + '})', 'g');
    
    return str.replace(regExPattern, '$1' + char);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    //first parameter: the string to be divided
    //second parameter: the character used to separate
    //third parameter: the number of characters in each division

    function separateStr(str, divider,  n)
    {
          var ret=[];

          for(let i=0; i<str.length; i=i+n) 
          {
                ret.push(str.substr(i, n))
          };

          return ret.join(divider);
    };

    separateStr('123456789', '.',  3);

    //Output: '123.456.789'
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to separate a `friendCode` for a mobile app but using [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

This will take a string, check every `n` characters and add delimiter at that location.

```
/**
 * A function to easily inject characters every 'n' spaces
 * @param {string} friendCode The string we want to inject characters in
 * @param {*} numDigits Determines the 'n' spaces we want to inject at
 * @param {*} delimiter The character(s) we want to inject
 */
function formatFriendCode(friendCode, numDigits, delimiter) {
  return Array.from(friendCode).reduce((accum, cur, idx) => {
    return accum += (idx + 1) % numDigits === 0 ? cur + delimiter : cur;
  }, '')
}

formatFriendCode("000011112222", 4, ' ')
// output "0000 1111 2222 "

formatFriendCode("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs.", 5, '$')
// output "The q$uick $brown$ fox $jumps$ over$ the $lazy $dogs.$"
```