# JavaScript regex pattern concatenate with variable

Tags: javascript, regex

How to create regex pattern which is concatenate with variable, something like this:

```
var test ="52";
var re = new RegExp("/\b"+test+"\b/"); 
alert('51,52,53'.match(re));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 183, accepted):

```
var re = new RegExp("/\b"+test+"\b/");
```

`\b` in a string literal is a backspace character. When putting a regex in a string literal you need one more round of escaping:

```
var re = new RegExp("\\b"+test+"\\b");
```

(You also don't need the `//` in this context.)

Comment: There are many places where the constructor-function of a built-in type may be used both with or without `new`. However, for consistency with other objects where this may not hold true, and clarity in general, I would always use `new`.

Comment: Another way is to use single-quotes for clarity so you don't need to escape the back-slashes: `new RegExp('\b'+test+'\b');`

Comment: You still need to escape the backslashes. Single quotes don't have different escaping rules to double quotes in JavaScript (unlike, say, PHP).

Comment: This answer also solves the same question when trying to use the border-operators on a variable with the .match() and .replace() JS regexing functions.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. The part about `When putting a regex in a string literal you need one more round of escaping`; is there any background information about (the reasons of) this?

Comment: CAn I use `body=body.replace('/'+reg+'/g', '')` instead of `new RegExp`?

Comment: @Timo No, your first argument is string not regex.

Answer (score 28):

With ES2015 (aka ES6) you can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) when constructing [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```js
let test = '53'
const regexp = new RegExp(`\\b${test}\\b`, 'gi') // showing how to pass optional flags
console.log('51, 52, 53, 54'.match(regexp))
```

Comment: typo: Regexp must be RegExp

Answer (score 8):

you can use

```
/(^|,)52(,|$)/.test('51,52,53')
```

but i suggest to use

```
var list = '51,52,53';
function test2(list, test){
    return !((","+list+",").indexOf(","+test+",") === -1)
}
alert( test2(list,52) )
```