# concat variable in regexp pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I use this regex

```
str = "asd34rgr888gfd98";
var p = str.match(/\d{2}/);
alert(p[0]);
```

butI not understood how can use variable as quantificator, that is how write this:

```
 var number = 2;
 var p = str.match(/\d{number}/);
```

P.S. I see this page [JavaScript regex pattern concatenate with variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712878/javascript-regex-pattern-concatenate-with-variable) 
but not understood how use example from these posts, in my case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to build your regex as a string and pass it to the [`RegExp` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
var regexString = '\\d{' + number + '}';
var regex = new RegExp(regexString);
var p = str.match(regex);
```

Notice that when building a regex via a string, you need to add some extra escape characters to escape the string as well as the regex.

Answer (score 4):

```
var number = "2"
var p = new RegExp("\\d{" + number + "}");
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
var str = "asd34rgr888gfd98";
number = 3;
p = str.match(new RegExp('\\d{' + number + '}'));

alert(p[0]);
```