# How to search for a substring and a regex in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, testcomplete

I have to verify if my string contains a substring followed by a regex.

Lets say the string looks like:  `"Abcd 03:02:01"`

How can i verify that the string contains the substring `"Abcd"` and the regex for `"03:02:01"`.
I am using jscript in TC9.

I tried using `find` for the Substring and checked regex using `Test`.This involves checking the input string twice in If loops.
But is there any other way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: `/Abcd \d\d:\d\d:\d\d/` (this requires it to be `Abcd DIGITDIGIT:DIGITDIGIT:DIGITDIGIT`).

Comment: Yes, why don't just include Abcd in the regex?

Comment: Thanks for you response. But how can i  use it to search in the input string.The string Abcd keeps changing ,hence cannot really add it in regex

Comment: Currently i am checking the input string in two parts.  var check=aqString.Find(Inputstring,"Abcd",0)   var matches=regex.test(Inputstring)  if(check !=1){  if(matches)  //do something  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [variables in a regex expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712878/javascript-regex-pattern-concatenate-with-variable).

```
var str = "Abcd 03:02:01";
var beginning = "Abcd"; 
var pattern= RegExp(beginning + " \\d\\d:\\d\\d\\:\\d\\d"); 
var result = pattern .test(str); //bool return
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well your question, you want to match the existence of `Abcd 03:02:01`in a string, based on that, you can use:

```
var s = "Abcd 03:02:01";
if (/^Abcd \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/.test(s)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```