# How to dynamically create regex to use in .match Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to dynamically create a regex to use in match function javascript.
How would that be possible?

```
var p = "*|";
var s = "|*";
"*|1387461375|* hello *|sfa|* *|3135145|* test".match(/"p"(\d{3,})"s"/g)
```

this would be the right regex:    `/\*\|(\d{3,})\|\*/g`

even if I add backslashes to p and s it doesn't work. Is it possible?

Comment: Just concatenate `p`, `"(\d{3,})"`, and `s` (escape `p` and `s` per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) is your friend:

```
var p = "\\*\\|", s = "\\|\\*"

var reg = new RegExp(p + '(\\d{3,})' + s, 'g')

"*|1387461375|* hello *|sfa|* *|3135145|* test".match(reg)
```

The key to making the dynamic regex global is to transform it into a `RegExp` object, and pass `'g'` in as the second argument.

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/os1yp5gb/).

Comment: beat me to it by about 15 seconds :).  It ends up as a bad regex, but it matches what the op asked

Comment: Although the `new` operator isn't required when creating instances of built-in objects, it's [still recommended.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712878/javascript-regex-pattern-concatenate-with-variable#comment2737765_2712896)

Comment: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /*|(d{3,})|*/: Nothing to repeat. I also tried escaping p and s without success

Comment: @AlexandruRada Edited. When using `RegExp`, you need to double escape.

Comment: right, I was only escaping and wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a `RegExp` object using your variables first. Also remember to escape `*` and `|` while forming `RegExp` object:

```
var p = "*|";
var s = "|*";
var re = new RegExp(p.replace(/([*|])/g, '\\$1')
                 + "(\\d{3,})" + 
                 s.replace(/([*|])/g, '\\$1'), "g");

var m = "*|1387461375|* hello *|sfa|* *|3135145|* test".match(re);
console.log(m);

//=> ["*|1387461375|*", "*|3135145|*"]
```