# Properly escape variable inside RegEx (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, regex

Didn’t want to ask, but I gave up :-( I can’t find the solution

I can’t get how to escape the variable/string.

```
var highlight_chars_count = {{highlight_chars_count}};
var regex_string = "/(^\\w{" + highlight_chars_count + "})/";
var regex = new RegExp(regex_string);
$('h1').html(function(i, v) {
    return v.replace(regex, "<span>$1</span>");
});
```

This pattern works (without " and a variable)

```
var regex = new RegExp(/(^\w{2})/);
```

I think the solution is here
[JavaScript regex pattern concatenate with variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712878/javascript-regex-pattern-concatenate-with-variable)
… but can’t transfer that to my regex.

The variable {{highlight_chars_count}} is a twig variable. Unfortunately I can’t insert the variable into the regex pattern either.

Comment: remove `/` in `var regex_string = "/(^\\w{" + highlight_chars_count + "})/";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need `/` and you can do without the capturing group:

```
var regex_string = "^\\w{" + highlight_chars_count + "}";
```

and then

```
return v.replace(regex, "<span>$&</span>"); 
                                ^
```

Note that the regex delimiters (`/.../`) are necessary when you declare a regex with a regex literal notation when a regex is static (e.g. `var rx = /abc/g`). Here, you use a *constructor notation*.

Also, `$&` backreference refers to the whole match text, so, no need enclosing the whole pattern with a capturing group.

[More information on `RegExp` regex literal and constructor notation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: Great tips! Thanks Wiktor.