# Javascript: Add Break after each 100 characters

Tags: javascript, text, character, break, line-breaks

If I write to long text for example this:

`aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`

The text is going out of the page, I have an idea to fix it, after every 100 characters I could make a `<br />` tag. But I don't know how to do it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You will find in reality this doesn't really cause a major problem.  Creating a long text string like that is usually only something that you would do in a testing environment.

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772941/how-can-i-insert-a-character-after-every-n-characters-in-javascript

Comment: This is not text. Normal text contains words (letters with spaces) and it breaks by your browser automatically.

Comment: Just to answer your question `str = str.replace(/(.{100})/g, "$1<br/>");`

Comment: without inserting </br> s.replace(/([^\n]{100})/g, '$1\n');

Comment: @DomreiRoam, unless the element in question has `white-space: pre;` or something similar that allows `\n` to carry through, you'd need a `<br>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the following CSS property on the element that you wish to force wrapping in:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

No need for any JavaScript!

If you *really* want to use JavaScript (for concept; CSS is better for accessibility and ease) then go ahead.

Oh, and another thing, if you're using a font that isn't monospace (but rather, proportional), cutting off at 100 characters could be ineffective. One line could have 100 'i' characters, with the next having another hundred 'm' chars, which are very different in size.

Oh, and *another* thing, you can't just apply a regex replace on the `innerHTML` unless it's all text. If there could possibly be other elements there, you must actually loop through the nodes, applying the technique to only text nodes.

Oh, and ***another*** thing, don't bother. Too many problems doing it with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code

```
str = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa';

len = str.length;
loop = len / 100;
document.write(loop);
document.write('<br>');

for(i=0; i<=loop; i++){
  document.write( str.slice( i*100, (i*100)+100) );
  document.write('<br>');
}
```