# How to replace word break with line break in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

Browsers inserts automatically a word break when text reaches the end of the box.
I would like to make this "invisible" to real `\n`.

Here is what I have tired:
http://jsbin.com/uraneq/1/edit

Example:
[image]

Comment: No, they don't automatically insert a line break (you can see for yourself by enlarging the textarea after the text has wrapped -- it will unwrap). The question is also very unclear.

Comment: If I type a text and if it reaches the end of the box the next word will appear in the next line (unless I pressed enter) I would like to detect this, and convert to real line breaks.

Comment: Why? Text layout should be performed when laying the text out, not when accepting input.

Comment: What you want is to save the text wrapped as it shows in the textarea? If this is what you are looking for, why?

Comment: why do you need that? Possibly there is better way to solve your problem. Making what you want is not a simple task as there is no any symbol that could be replaced.

Comment: If your textarea uses a fixed-width font like on the screenshots, just add a `\n` every *n* characters. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1772941/825789

Comment: because I would like to generate a SVG from this text and I need to know, where the text does not fit the fixed size area.

Comment: @bfavaretto They dont have a fixed length.

Comment: @bfavaretto, it is much complex. Browsers don't cut the word in two. If the textarea line is for 10 chars and you start a (long) word at 8th pos, it will be shown entirely in the next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [`wrap="hard"`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-button-element.html#attr-textarea-wrap) attribute for `TEXTAREA` element. Older browsers support `physical` value which has similar meaning as `hard` (but is invalid at least in HTML5).

Comment: "If you set it to physical the text is submitted exactly as it appears on the screen - linebreaks included." thats right, but how can I get that value?

Comment: For example, in PHP, posted data is in `$_POST` array. In client side, it's unlikely possible to retrieve such modified data. Take into account that `physical` is nonstandard value anyway, and `hard` should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

`&#8203;` will not be auto inserted by the browser itself so you cannot match it in auto broken text.

however.. you can match line length to see when there might be a possible linebreak (in case you use a block font)