# Regex reads from right to left

Tags: javascript, regex

I was looking for a short code that can put commas in set of numbers until I came to [this site](http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic.html).

The code:

```
function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

Works really great. Having this example set of number:

```
addCommas('83475934.89');
```

Will return `"83,475,934.89"`, but when I read the code, I expect it to return `8,3,4,7,5,934.89` but this sites explains that

> `\d+` in combination with `\d{3}` will match a group of 3 numbers preceded by any amount of numbers. This tricks the search into replacing from right to left.

And I get so confused.
How does this code read from right to left? Plus, what does `$1` and `$2` mean?

Comment: `$1` and `$2` represent the capture groups

Comment: It doesn't _read_ from right to left, it _replaces_ from right to left. Sort of. Note that you can make the function even shorter - a really minor change to the regex removes the need to do the `split()` on the decimal point, saving three lines of code: http://jsfiddle.net/TqCRh/

Comment: @nnnnnn - We could go even further by replacing the whole function by this line of code I think. subjectString.replace(/\d+?(?=(?:\d{3})+\D)/img, "$&,");

Comment: Looks like I should've said subjectString.replace(/\d+?(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:\D|$))/img, "$&,");

Comment: @FrancisGagnon - Doing it in one step with a single regex was beyond me. Yours is close but it incorrectly inserts commas amongst the digits after the decimal point.

Comment: @nnnnnn - You're right. I think this next regex would fix that but it uses a positive lookbehind, so it wouldn't work in Javascript. So I guess it doesn't matter. Oh Well. (?<=(?:[^\d.]|^)\d*)(\d+?)(?=(?:\d{3})+\b)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It matches from right to left because it uses **greedy pattern matching**. This means that it first finds all the digits (the \d+), **then** tries to find the \d{3}. In the number 2421567.56, for example it would first match the digits up until the '.' - 2431567 - then works backwards to match the next 3 digits (567) in the next part of the regex. It does this in a loop adding a comma between the $1 and $2 variables.

The $'s represent matching groups formed in the regex with parentheses e.g. the (\d+) = $1 and (\d{3}) = $2. In this way it can easily add characters between them.

In the next iteration, the greedy matching stops at the newly created comma instead, and it continues until it can't match > 3 digits.

Answer (score 15):

It isn't *actually* reading right-to-left. What's really happening is that it's repeatedly applying the `(\d+)(\d{3})` pattern (via a while loop) and replacing until it no longer matches the pattern. In other words:

Iteration 1:

```
x1 = 83475934.89
x1.replace((\d+)(\d{3}), '$1' + ',' + '$2');
x1 = 83475,934.89
```

Iteration 2:

```
x1 = 83475,934.89
x1.replace((\d+)(\d{3}), '$1' + ',' + '$2');
x1 = 83,475,934.89
```

Iteration 3:

```
x1 = 83,475,934.89
x1.replace((\d+)(\d{3}), '$1' + ',' + '$2');
// no match; end loop
```

---

**Edit:**

> Plus, what does $1 and $2 mean?

Those are back references to the matching groups `(\d+)` and `(\d{3})` respectively.

Here's a great reference for learning how Regular Expressions actually work:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Comment: Better way of explaining it.

Comment: In Iteration 1, can I expect the result to be `834,75934.89` ?

Comment: @fiberOptics No. 834,75934.89 is `(\d+)(\d{5})`.

Comment: @fiberOptics - Add a `console.log(x1)` inside the `while` loop and you'll see exactly what is happening on each iteration.

Comment: Utopia's answer explains why this is. The `\d+` part uses **greedy matching** -- that is, it will match as many characters as it can before moving on to the next part. You can modify this behavior, by the way -- at the following link, read "Laziness Instead of Greediness": http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: +1 @BrianLacy Thanks a lot for your answer, but I will accept Utopia's answer since it was explained clearly as my mind understood. :)

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a regular expression which does the same thing in a single pass:

```
/(?!\b)(\d{3}(?=(\d{3})*\b))/g
```

---

Try this for example with varying numbers at the start:

```js
var num = '1234567890123456';

for(var i = 1; i <= num.length; i++)
{
  console.log(num.slice(0, -i).replace(/(?!\b)(\d{3}(?=(\d{3})*\b))/g, ',$1'));
}
```

---

I'll try to break it down here:

Ignore this bit for now - I'll come back to that.

> **(?!\b)**(\d{3}(?=(\d{3})*\b))

It still reads from left to right trying to capture blocks of 3 digits. Here's the capturing group.

> (?!\b)**(\d{3}**(?=(\d{3})*\b)**)**

However, inside the capturing group, it uses a lookahead.

> (?!\b)(\d{3}**(?=**(\d{3})*\b**)**)

The lookahead looks for any multiple of 3 digits anchored to the end of the number - the terminating boundary. This aligns the capture to multiples of 3 *from the right-hand end of the number*. This means it works with decimal numbers too (unless they are more than 3 decimal places, in which case it will put commas in them too. It ain't perfect).

> (?!\b)(\d{3}(?=**(\d{3})*\b**))

The problem I had was that JavaScript doesn't support atomic look-behinds so, when the number has a multiple of 3 digits, it was matching the first 3 digits and placing a comma at the very start of the number. 
You can't match a character before the 3 digit match without throwing off the repetition, so I had to use a negative lookahead that matches a word-boundary. It's kinda the opposite of putting `^` at the start.

> **(?!\b)**(\d{3}(?=(\d{3})*$))

Essentially it prevents the expression from matching from the start of the string.
Which would be bad.

Answer (score 3):

This explanation was further down on the same page

> **Code Explanation**: The code starts off dividing the string into two
>   parts (**nStr** and **nStrEnd**) if there is a decimal. A regular expression
>   is used on **nStr** to add the commas. Then **nStrEnd** is added back. If the
>   string didn't have **nStrEnd** temporarily removed, then the regular
>   expression would format **10.0004** as **10.0,004**
>
> **Regular Expression Explanation**: **\d+** in combination with **\d{3}** will
>   match a group of 3 numbers preceded by any amount of numbers. This
>   tricks the search into replacing from right to left.

The `$1` and `$2` are captured group matches from the regular expression. You can read more on this topic on [Regex Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: +1 for sharing the same link as me :) well that and, you know, for providing a good answer (using the OP's own source)!

Answer (score 2):

The code does read from right to left, what it does is searching for the biggest row of digits `(\d+)` that is followed by 3 digits `(\d{3})`. The $1 and $2 are respectively the biggest row of digits and the 3 digits. So it place the comma in between them, by repeating this process it can parse it this way.

Answer (score 0):

just reversed the string

```js
function addCommas(num_as_string) {
    // convert into string
    num_as_string+='';
    if (num_as_string === "") {
        return num_as_string;
    }
    /* add more test here*/
    // split the integer part and decimal part
    let [integer_part, decimal_part] = num_as_string.split('.');
    if (decimal_part === undefined) {
        decimal_part = '';
    } else {
        decimal_part = '.' + decimal_part;
    }

    return integer_part.split('').reverse().join('').match(/\d\d?\d?/g).reverse().map(v => v.split('').reverse().join('')).join(',') + decimal_part;
}
```

Output:

```
addCommas('83475934.89')
"83,475,934.89"

addCommas(83475934.89)
"83,475,934.89"

addCommas(83475934)
"83,475,934"
```