# Putting space after specific character count javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a script which will put a space after every 4 digits to achieve this I write a script which works fine

this is like

```
function putSpace(el, after) {
        putSapceAfter = putSapceAfter || 4;
        var v = el.value.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, ''),
            reg = new RegExp(".{" + putSapceAfter + "}","g")
        el.value = v.replace(reg, function (a, b, c) {
            return a + ' ';
        });
    }

    var el = document.getElementById('numerDom');
    el.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
        putSpace(this, 5);
    });
```

Now if the number start from 6011 or 65 then I want to put a first space after 4 digit and then after every 5 digit inside text box for rest other put a space after every 4 digits.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
String.prototype.chunk = function(n) {
    var ret = [];
    for(var i=0, len=this.length; i < len; i += n) {
       ret.push(this.substr(i, n))
    }
    return ret
};

function insertSpace() {
  // Disregard everything bar digits and captals
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, '')

  // Start with 6011 or 65
  var hit = this.value.match(/^(6011|65)/);

  if(hit){
    var part_1 = this.value.slice(0,4),
        part_2 = this.value.slice(4).chunk(5).join(" ");

    if(part_1.length === 4){
      this.value = part_1 + " " + part_2;
    }
  } else {
    this.value = this.value.chunk(4).join(" ");
  }
}

var el = document.getElementById('numerDom');
el.addEventListener('keyup', insertSpace, false);
```

I got the `String.prototype.chunk` function from here: 
[How can I insert a character after every n characters in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772941/how-can-i-insert-a-character-after-every-n-characters-in-javascript)

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/B4x6Y/).

Comment: can we do this using jquery?

Comment: Err, jQuery is JavaScript.