# Put line break after 10 characters in text area

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text area that can take 10000 characters. i want to put the line breaker on **each line** of the text area value after 10 character

something like this i want to achive

```
11111111 1
111 111 11
11 11 11 1
```

all above line has 10 characters each.

```
var start = 3
var times = 1;
$('.mydesc').keyup(function () {
    var len = $(this).val().length;
    if (len == start) {
        this.value += '\n';
        times = ++times;
        start= ((start * 2) + start);
    }
});
```

but doesn't work ..

Comment: Actually I did not get the line "start= ((start * 2) + start);" , why not just "start * 3" ?

Comment: Do you want to store the line breaks, or just have them shown in the textarea for formatting purposes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I insert a character after every n characters in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772941/how-can-i-insert-a-character-after-every-n-characters-in-javascript)

Answer (score 7):

Simplest solution is to always re-add all of the new-lines:

```
$('.mydesc').keyup(function () {
    this.value = this.value
                     .replace(/[\n\r]+/g, "")
                     .replace(/(.{10})/g, "$1\n");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s4cUz/

Comment: thanks its worked, using your solution after 8 years since you posted,

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/Zxuj7/

```
$('#test_textarea').keyup(function () {
   var new_stuff = $(this).val();
       new_stuff = new_stuff.replace(/[\n\r]+/g,""); // clean out newlines, so we dont get dups!
   var test = new_stuff.replace(/(.{10})/g,"$1\n");
   $(this).val(test);
});
```

However, be aware that it doesn't work that well with the "deleting" of characters. If you give it a go, you will notice that when you actually delete a character and the code runs, it will put you at the end of the textarea again (because its "overwriting" the value)

**UPDATE:**

You may actually be better formatting AFTER they have finished editing the textarea - i.e using **blur()**;

```
$('#test_textarea').blur(function () {
    // leaving the field... so lets try and format nicely now
    var new_stuff = $(this).val();
           new_stuff = new_stuff.replace(/[\n\r]+/g,""); // clean out newlines, so we dont get dups!
           new_stuff = new_stuff.replace(/(.{10})/g,"$1\n");
    $(this).val(new_stuff);
});
```

Although that doesn't do it in real time - it does work better when deleting/editing the contents

Answer (score 1):

Enhanced version of Andrew Newby's script:

```
$('#test_textarea').keyup(function (e) {
     if (e.keyCode === 8) return; // Backspace
     var new_stuff = $(this).val();
     new_stuff = new_stuff.replace(/[\n\r]+/g,""); // clean out newlines, so we dont get dups!
     new_stuff = new_stuff.replace(/(.{10})/g,"$1\n");
     $(this).val(new_stuff);
});
```

This actually ignores backspace key, so at least that interaction is preserved.