# Add Space After every 4 number characters in text box with help of jquery while entering value

Tags: jquery

I trying to write a script using jQuery, it is suppose to automatically put a space after every numbers. in order to separate a sequence of numbers that user input in an input field. e.g. 4444 4444 4444 4444

```
$('#creditcardnumber').blur(function(){
  var creditcardnumber= $(this), val = creditcardnumber.val();
  if(val.length > 4)
    creditcardnumber.val(val.slice(0, -4)+' '+val.slice(-4));
})
```

Comment: where is the script you wrote?

Comment: "I trying to write a script using jQuery", what it is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I insert a character after every n characters in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772941/how-can-i-insert-a-character-after-every-n-characters-in-javascript)

Comment: instead of using `blur` use `focusout` event as shown in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6wgoe5s8/

Comment: `var buffer = val.substr(0, 4); for (var i = 4, len = val.length; i < len; i += 4) { buffer += ' ' + val.substr(i, 4); }` should work fine (the result will be in `buffer`)

Answer (score 0):

var number= 4444444444444444;

```
alert(("" + number).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " "));

$('#creditcardnumber').blur(function(){
    var creditcardnumber = $(this), val = creditcardnumber.val();

    creditcardnumber.val(("" + number).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " "));
})
```

Here two lookahead assertions use in regex :

1. one to look for any point in the string that has a multiple of 3 digits in a row after it,
2. another assertion to make sure that point only has exactly a multiple of 3 digits.