# Javascript/Regex for formatting a string as you type

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string, which at most can have 14 characters including whitespace. It will be formatted like this at `str.len === 14`:

`var str = 'A1 B2 C3 D4 E5'`

I have an empty text field that a user is typing text into. Once they type two characters, (`'A1'`) I need to add a trailing space to the string. The next character they type would cause the string to look like this:

`'A1 B'`

I am using javascript and need either a javascript or regex solution for formatting my string as a user types. There should be no leading whitespace, a whitespace after every two non-whitespace characters, and no more than 14 characters including whitespace (There is no trailing whitespace at the end of the 14th character).

So far, I've tried this:

`str.replace(/(..)/g,"$1 ")`

But, that only works if `str` is already a 10 character string. As you're typing the whitespaces are added to the string and it throws off the index.

I also tried some combinations if using javascript the % operator that worked fine as long as you were entering a string. But then if a user edited a 7 character string by adding onto the beginning of the string, it threw off everything:

```
if (str.length === 14) {
    return;
}
if (str.length > 0 && str.length % 3 === 2) {
    newValue = newValue + ' ';
}
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772941/how-can-i-insert-a-character-after-every-n-characters-in-javascript

Comment: And this is going to happen _while_ the user is typing? God, I hate when websites do that. Don't mess with my input!

Comment: @Ejay That format only works with a predetermined string. It will not work as you are typing

Comment: @NullUserException Indeed. After every character you type this formatter will receive the new string and reformat it.

Comment: @JonathanAMcCann yes and you can use it to format your string after each character input.

Comment: @Ejay if you type 2 characters, it works fine. But then pass any of those regexes a string like this : `string = 'AA '` with an already trailing whitespace and it will break. Then try `'AA B'`, etc.

Comment: So if the user wants to correct their input (eg change `AB CD EE` to `AA BB CC`) the cursor is going to jump around? Or if they want to edit a mistake in between spaces characters are going to magically shift all over the place? (eg: I want to change the `AB` to `AA` in `AA AB AC CC`; if I erase the `B` the string will turn into `AA AA CC C`, confusing me?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3qg38eof/

Comment: @Ejay Cursor keys broken; any edits to the middle of the string magically jump the cursor to the end. This is why I hate when websites stubbornly mess with my input

Comment: @null of course, and there is no limit on input length as well. I was just trying to show that this method works as well :) Thanks for bringing up the usability issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're expecting people to input *HEX*, why not be more strict and remove & re-add the spaces each time, then limit the input

```
var str = 'A1B';
str.replace(/0x|[^0-9a-zA-Z]/g, '').replace(/(..)(?!$)/g, '$1 ').slice(0, 14);
// "A1 B"
// and possibly set cursor position
// (do the char removal on [0..old_pos] to figure out char difference to new_pos)
```

This will also solve pasting or typing in the middle of the input etc as the spaces will always move to where they should be

```
// or e.g. str = 'A1B2C3D4E5F6'; // longer than expected
// becomes
// "A1 B2 C3 D4 E5"
```

---

Extra notes

- I strip `0x` because it's a common hex prefix which you don't need but could be pasted in
- The `(?!$)` prevents a trailing space
- Your maximum length should always be `3x - 1` for some positive integer `x` (this is true for `14`)

Comment: Quality, thanks man. I'm also using EXT JS and sometimes the events don't fire in time if you type text fast enough. This solves that problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the most elegant code, but I'd have the code follow the following process after every keyup that adds a letter or number:

1. Get cursor position
2. Get string
3. Strip all spaces from string
4. Re-add spaces in the positions you want
5. Put the cursor back where it was

Answer (score 0):

A solution with the [formatter.js](https://jaridmargolin.github.io/formatter.js/) library:

```js
new Formatter(document.getElementById('text'), {
  'pattern': '{{**}} {{**}} {{**}} {{**}} {{**}}'
});
```

```html
<script src="http://firstopinion.github.io/formatter.js/javascripts/formatter.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text" />
```