# Change input field on keyup to match MAC address format

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts, tampermonkey

I don't have much experience with JavaScript or jQuery.

I tried to use Tampermonkey to auto correct the input field for a MAC address.

The site wants a MAC address formatted as `00:00:00:00:00:00`.

So I wrote this script for Tampermonkey so it automatically adds the colons while I'm typing:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Name
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Adds colons to the mac adress of the Mac Field
// @author       You
// @match        Somesite
// @grant        none
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
// ==/UserScript==
document.getElementById("MAC").addEventListener('keyup', function() { 
  var mac = document.getElementById('MAC').value;
  var macs = mac.split('');
  var colons = ["2", "5", "8", "11", "14"];
  for (var col in colons) {
    if (macs[col] == "-") {
      macs[col] = ":";
    } else if (macs[col] != "") {

    } else if (macs[col] != ":") {
      var colo = col + 1;
      macs[colo] = macs[col];
      macs[col] = ":";
    }
  }
  mac = macs.toString();
});
```

```html
<input id=MAC />
```

But it don't work. The ID of the inputfield is `MAC`.

Where and how much did I do wrong?

SOLUTION

Thanks to @i-wrestled-a-bear-once and @freginold for the , my oppion, best solutions

I'm using now a slightly changed version from @freginold

```
var back = true;
function isHex(char) {
  // check if char is a hex char
  if (!isNaN(parseInt(char))) {
    return true;
  } else {
    switch (char.toLowerCase()) {
      case "a":
      case "b":
      case "c":
      case "d":
      case "e":
      case "f":
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
document.getElementById("MAC").addEventListener('keydown', function() {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;

   if( key == 8 || key == 46 ) {
       back = false;
   }
});

document.getElementById("MAC").addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;


  var mac = document.getElementById('MAC').value;
  var newMac = mac.replace("-", ""); // remove any dashes
  if ((isHex(mac[mac.length - 1]) && (isHex(mac[mac.length - 2])) && (mac.length <= 16) && (back))) {
    // if last two chars are numbers, insert a colon
    newMac = newMac + ":";

  }
back = true;
  document.getElementById('MAC').value = newMac; // put new value into input field

});
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: The immediate problem is that you don't do anything with the results of the function (presumably you want to set the field value to `mac`).  There are other logic problems with the text replacement, but that's the first step.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I insert a character after every n characters in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772941/how-can-i-insert-a-character-after-every-n-characters-in-javascript)

Comment: @rmlan how can i debug it in Tampermonkey?
@daniel-beck ohh yeah with the `mac = macs.toString();`part i totally had a logic mistake xD . changed it to `document.getElementById('MAC').value = macs.toString();`and now it enters in the field. now i can searc hthe error in the **correction logic** because i get a lot of commas in the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify it and check if the last two characters in the string are hex characters (0-9, A-F) and if so, insert a `:`. You can also use `.replace()` to remove any occurrence of `-` if you (or someone else) types a dash instead of a colon.

That way you can cover inserting colons if you don't type them at all, as well as converting any typed dashes to colons.

Here's a working example:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Name
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Adds colons to the mac adress of the Mac Field
// @author       You
// @match        Somesite
// @grant        none
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
// ==/UserScript==
function isHex(char) {
  if (!isNaN(parseInt(char))) {
    return true;
  } else {
    switch (char.toLowerCase()) {
      case "a":
      case "b":
      case "c":
      case "d":
      case "e":
      case "f":
        return true;
        break;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

document.getElementById("MAC").addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  var mac = document.getElementById('MAC').value;
  if (mac.length < 2) {
    return;
  }
  var newMac = mac.replace("-", "");
  if ((isHex(mac[mac.length - 1]) && (isHex(mac[mac.length - 2])))) {
    newMac = newMac + ":";
  }
  document.getElementById('MAC').value = newMac;
});

document.getElementById('MAC').focus(); // autofocus for testing
```

```html
<input id=MAC />
```

Comment: hey it works so far with Numbers. is the a function like `isNaN()` for HEX digits? cause mac addresses have ABCDEF as well in it ^^

Comment: @HitmareChelien Didn't think about that! There's no native JS function, but I can code it in. Give me a minute.

Comment: @HitmareChelien Try it now.

Comment: hey thanks it work now. i did a small adjustment to it so it don't writes any unnessesary colons at the end of the actual mac address
`if ((isHex(mac[mac.length - 1]) && (isHex(mac[mac.length - 2])) && (mac.length <= 17))) {`

Comment: Ah, nice addition.

Comment: now i have to filter out key presses from the Backspace key so it don't enters the colon every time i delete it xD

Comment: @HitmareChelien Is this just for your personal use? Sounds like it could be pretty useful code once you're done.

Comment: my intend was more like open source. if someone have this problem as well ^^

Comment: You could replace the repeated getElementById `var mac = document.getElementById('MAC').value;` with `var mac = this.value;`

Answer (score 7):

- `replace(/[^\d|A-Z]/g, '')` removes any non alphanumeric chars
- `match(/.{1,2}/g)` breaks the string into chunks of 2
- `join(":")` joins the chunks and puts a colon in between them

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Name
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Adds colons to the mac adress of the Mac Field
// @author       You
// @match        Somesite
// @grant        none
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
// ==/UserScript==
document.getElementById("MAC").addEventListener('keyup', function() { 
  // remove non digits, break it into chunks of 2 and join with a colon
  this.value = 
    (this.value.toUpperCase()
    .replace(/[^\d|A-Z]/g, '')
    .match(/.{1,2}/g) || [])
    .join(":")
});
```

```html
<input id=MAC />
```

Comment: it deletes the ABCDF of my mac address as well :/ . but with numbers only it works

Comment: When type a letter as the first char, I get this error: `"Unable to get property 'join' of undefined or null reference`. When I type a number as the first char then a letter, it erases the letter.

Comment: @freginold - SO is not a free code writing service. My intent was never to write his code for him, it was to show him how to do it. My answer before was sufficient because it gave him all the tools he needed. But if you insist, I'll do some hand-holding. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Not insisting anything; just pointing out where it didn't work.

Comment: i hope i didn't do anything wrong o.o. I'm very grateful about your codes and i have to admit that i'm learning as well from finished codes as well as from hints.

Comment: @HitmareChelien - You didn't do anything wrong (I actually upvoted your question), just a little frustrated that I lost an upvote for improving my answer when the improvement shouldn't have been necessary in the first place. Did this answer do what you wanted? If so feel free to mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`chunk`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772941/how-can-i-insert-a-character-after-every-n-characters-in-javascript): (not my code, I just included it and modified your code to work with it.)

```
function chunk(str, n) {
    var ret = [];
    var i;
    var len;

    for(i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i += n) {
       ret.push(str.substr(i, n))
    }

    return ret
};
```

Then your code should look like:

```
document.getElementById("MAC").addEventListener('keyup', function() { 
  var mac = document.getElementById('MAC').value;
  var macs = mac.split(':').join('');
  macs = chunk(macs, 2).join(':');
  document.getElementById('MAC').value = macs.toString();
});
```

**demo**

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Name
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Adds colons to the mac adress of the Mac Field
// @author       You
// @match        Somesite
// @grant        none
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
// ==/UserScript==
document.getElementById("MAC").addEventListener('keyup', function() { 
  var mac = document.getElementById('MAC').value;
  var macs = mac.split(':').join('');
  macs = chunk(macs, 2).join(':');
  document.getElementById('MAC').value = macs.toString();
});

function chunk(str, n) {
    var ret = [];
    var i;
    var len;

    for(i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i += n) {
       ret.push(str.substr(i, n))
    }

    return ret
};
```

```html
<input id=MAC maxlength="17"/>
```

Comment: the code don't work
`mac.split(':').join('');` would probably do nothing because a MAC Address like `A0B1C2D3E4F5` is entered . i changed it to `var macs = mac.split('').join('');` but it still didn't show any changes in the input field.

but thanks anyway  for the afford

Comment: if i enter `A0B1C2D3E4F5` then it works just fine on mine

Answer (score 0):

Just tried a simple logic.

```js
var macelem = document.getElementById("MAC");
macelem.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    var mac = macelem.value,index=(mac.match(/\:/g)||[]).length;
    if(index < 5 && index*3+2 == mac.length)
    {
        mac += ":";index++;
    }
    macelem.value = mac.substr(0,17);
});
```

```html
<input id="MAC">
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you, you replace or add the ":" where it is needed.
Then you cap the length of the string before you add it back to the input, to avoid getting to long MAC addresses.

Btw, you had some problems with your colons[col] slection to get your code to work.

```js
document.getElementById("MAC").addEventListener('keyup', function() { 
  var mac = document.getElementById('MAC').value;
  var macs = mac.split('');
  var colons = [2, 5, 8, 11, 14];
  for (var col in colons) {
   if (colons[col] <= macs.length) {
      if (macs[colons[col]] !== ":") {
        macs.splice(colons[col], 0, ":");
      }
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('MAC').value = macs.join('').substring(0,17);
});
```

```html
<input id=MAC />
```

Answer (score 0):

built on @KungWaz's answer by using jQuery and supporting backspace/delete

```js
$("#MAC").keydown(function(e) {
  // firefox has different values for keys
  if ([186, 189, 59, 173, 32].includes(e.which))
    return false;
});

$("#MAC").keyup(function(e) {
  let start = $(this).prop("selectionStart")
  let end = $(this).prop("selectionEnd")
  let addedColon = false
  // ignore backspace and delete
  if ([8, 46].includes(e.which)) {
    return true
  }
  var macs = $(this).val().split('');
  var colons = [2, 5, 8, 11, 14];
  for (var col in colons) {
    if (colons[col] <= macs.length) {
      if (macs[colons[col]] !== ":") {
        if (macs[colons[col] - 1] == ":" || macs[colons[col] + 1] == ":") {
          // dont add colon if there is one nearby
          // that way you can edit the middle of the mac address
          continue
        }
        macs.splice(colons[col], 0, ":");
        addedColon = true
        $(this).focus()
      }
    }
  }
  $(this).val(macs.join('').substring(0, 17))
  if (start == end && addedColon) {
    //if not selecting text
    $(this)[0].setSelectionRange(start + 1, end + 1)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id=MAC maxlength="17"/>
```