# Add comma after every 3rd character in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I would like to add `comma` after every third character of the string.

I tried [Adding comma after some character in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772941/how-can-i-insert-a-character-after-every-n-characters-in-javascript)

I also tried using regex

```
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs.".replace(/(.{3})/g,",")
```

But didn't work for me.

Comment: `.replace(/(.{3})/g,"$1,")` - you forgot to put back what you captured. Or, [`.replace(/.{3}/g,"$&,")`](https://regex101.com/r/FrXajO/1)

Comment: Do you want the space to be counted?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you replace the characters with the comma rather than replacing the characters with themselves PLUS the comma - use the following regex:

```js
var str = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs.'.replace(/.{3}/g, '$&,');
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `split()` and `join()` operations for that output:

```js
var str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs.";
var strArray = str.split('');
for(var i=1; i<=strArray.length; i++){
  if(i%3 === 0){
    strArray[i] = '*' + strArray[i];
  }
}
str = strArray.join('').replace(/\*/g,',');
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs.";

function addComma(text){
 let chunks = [];
 for(let i = 0; i < text.length; i+=3){
   chunks.push(text.substr(i,3));
 }
 return chunks.join();
}
console.log(addComma(text));
```