# How to Add space between every 4 characters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, split

I want to add a space between every 4 characters. I'm developing a webpage about credit card numbers.

example

```
var x = document.getElementById("card_number").value;
```

**example :** 
if the value of x is 1234567890123456

I need to split this number every 4 characters and add a space. Like this

**1234 5678 9012 3456**

and I need this number on a **variable**. Because I need to set this number on the textbox. 
Please help me. thanks

Comment: Simular question like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772941/how-can-i-insert-a-character-after-every-n-characters-in-javascript use the search function

Comment: [Alternative search](https://www.google.nl/search?q=style+OR+format+credit+card+number+JavaScript+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use RegEx for this

```js
const dummyTxt = '1234567890123456';

const joy = dummyTxt.match(/.{1,4}/g);
console.log(joy.join(' '));
```

Comment: It do not add a space, it split it up

Comment: Yes, @GrégoryNEUT I have edited my answer now.

Answer (score 15):

You could look for four characters with a positive lookahead for more characters and insert a space after each block.

```js
function format(s) {
    return s.toString().replace(/\d{4}(?=.)/g, '$& ');
}

console.log(format(1234567890123456));
```

Comment: Btw, isn't `replace(/\w...` better because IBANs sometimes start with `FR` or alike.

Answer (score 4):

Without regex, you can use `map` as well to achieve this

```js
let x = '1234567890123456'

let res = [...x].map((d, i) => (i) % 4 == 0 ? ' ' + d : d).join('').trim()

console.log(res)
```

Comment: It shows values with space like above. but not working in the insert input value.