# How to append a string to another string after every N char?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am trying to create a program that adds "gav" after every second letter, when the string is written.

```
var string1  = "word"
```

#### Expected output:

```
wogavrdgav
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I insert a character after every n characters in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772941/how-can-i-insert-a-character-after-every-n-characters-in-javascript)

Comment: `string1.replace(/(.{2})/g,"$1gav")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the modulus operator for this -

```js
var string1  = "word";

function addGav(str){
  var newStr = '';
  var strArr = str.split('');

  strArr.forEach(function(letter, index){
    index % 2 == 1
      ? newStr += letter + 'gav'
      : newStr += letter
  })
  return newStr;
}

console.log(addGav(string1)); // gives wogavrdgav

console.log(addGav('gavgrif')) //gives gagavvggavrigavf....
```

Answer (score 0):

#### RegEx

Here, we can add a quantifier to `.` (which matches all chars except for new lines) and design an expression with one capturing group (`$1`):

```
(.{2})
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wFEGoj/1/)

---

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /(.{2})/gm;
const str = `AAAAAA`;
const subst = `$1bbb`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

---

If you wish to consider new lines as a char, then this expression would do that:

```
([\s\S]{2})
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qOTFGh/1)

[image]

[image]

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /([\s\S]{2})/gm;
const str = `ABCDEF
GHIJK
LMNOP
QRSTU
VWXYZ
`;
const subst = `$1bbb`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const string1 = 'word'
console.log('Input:', string1)
const newStr = string1.replace(/(?<=(^(.{2})+))/g, 'gav')
console.log('Output:', newStr)
```

- `.{2}`: 2 any character
- `(.{2})+`:  match 2 4 6 8 any character
- `^(.{2})+`:  match 2 4 6 8 any character from start, if don't have `^`, this regex will match from any position
- `?<=(regex_group)`: match something after `regex_group`
- `g`: match all

This way is finding 2,4,6, etc character from the start of the string and don't match this group so it will match `''` before 2,4,6, etc character and replace with `'gav'`

Example with `word`:

match `wo`, `word` and ignore it, match something before that(`''`) and replace with `'gav'` with method `replace`