# What's the opposite of a nbsp?

Tags: html, character, line-breaks, hyphenation

A `&nbsp;` character is a space which doesn't allow for line breaking.

```
<p>lorem ipsum here&nbsp;are&nbsp;some&nbsp;words and so on</p>

| lorem ipsum                |
| here are some words and so |
| on                         |
```

What's the opposite of that? That is, a character which is NOT rendered as a space, but CAN be used for line breaking.

```
<p>foo supercalifragilisticexpialidocious bar</p>
<!--   put char here ^   and here ^ -->

|foo supercalifragi |
|listicexpiali      |
|docious bar        |

or with wider size:

|foo supercalifragilisticexpiali   |
|docious bar                       |
```

I'm aware of the [soft-hyphen character](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.3), but for my purposes, I specifically do *not* want a hyphen added at the break.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You want the unicode character ZERO-WIDTH SPACE (\u200B).

You can get it in HTML with `&#8203;` or `&#x200b;`.

> Explicit breaks and non-breaks:
>
> LB7 : Do not break before spaces or zero width space.
> LB8 : Break before any character following a zero-width space, even if one or more spaces intervene.
> http://unicode.org/reports/tr14/

Comment: I tested this, it does not produce a line break in Firefox 3.5.7.

Comment: It's not meant to produce an explicit linebreak. It's meant to indicate a point where the line *can* be wrapped if it's too long to fit in wherever it's supposed to go.

Comment: So.... this character can be evil because if you copy content around that contains it (in unicode-aware editors that will happily play along) you will be unaware of its presence, and it will cause e.g. compilers to choke on it. hard. For example Chrome will tell you "ILLEGAL CHARACTER" but not point out to you where it is. I'd use this admittedly neat trick as a very last resort

Comment: It should be called a "Non Space Break"

Comment: It's visible alternative is a Hyphen.

Answer (score 38):

There also is the little-known [wbr tag](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html), which lets the browser to decide whether to break the line or not.

Comment: It should be noted that this is non-standard, and not supported in all browsers.

Comment: @Brian, check the quirksmode link fredden posted.

Comment: If it's good enough for Facebook, it's good enough for every one ;-)

Comment: WBR works in Chrome 34.0.1847.131 m, Firefox 29.0.1, and Opera Chromium 12.17. It does not work in IE 11.0.9600.17105.

Comment: does <wbr> add an `-` ?

Comment: @beppe9000 You may want to have a look at [`&shy;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/226464/7669319)

Answer (score 17):

There's a nice page over at quirksmode.org that answers this question quite nicely IMHO. http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html

In short: use <wbr /> or &#8203; (or &shy; but you mentioned you don't want the dash).

Comment: Not all of these possibilities are supported by all browsers. I guess &#8203; is the best solution as most browsers should be able to recognize Unicode.

Comment: and IE6 users get an ugly glyph apparently... my heart weeps.

Answer (score 4):

use [<wbr>](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS3 property called [word-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap)

```
p.test {word-wrap:break-word;}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This works only if you don't care where the line break is added.

Comment: The question is to set a position in a specific word where to break, not how to enable work break in general.

Answer (score -5):

theres a lot of discussion about this but it has become more or less standard to use `&shy;`

Comment: This is a soft hyphen, which the asker didn't want.