# How to force a line break in a long word in a DIV?

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

Okay, this is really confusing me. I have some content inside of a div like so:

```
<div style="background-color: green; width: 200px; height: 300px;">

Thisisatest.Thisisatest.Thisisatest.Thisisatest.Thisisatest.Thisisatest.

</div>
```

However, the content overflows the DIV (as expected) because the 'word' is too long.

How can I force the browser to 'break' the word where necessary to fit all of the content inside?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046530/whats-the-opposite-of-a-nbsp

Comment: `&shy;` breaks the word with a hyphon.

Answer (score 800, accepted):

<strike>Use [`word-wrap:break-word;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/word-wrap)</strike>

It even works in IE6, which is a pleasant surprise.

---

`word-wrap: break-word` has been replaced with [`overflow-wrap: break-word;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) which works in every modern browser. IE, being a dead browser, will forever rely on the deprecated and non-standard `word-wrap` instead.

Existing uses of `word-wrap` today still work as it is an alias for `overflow-wrap` per the specification.

Comment: Actually, word-wrap is an IE invention. So no surprise that it works in IE :)

Comment: For this to work in a table, you may need to apply the `table-layout: fixed;` to the table

Comment: `word-wrap: break-word` didn't work for me but `word-break: break-word` as @rahul suggested below worked.

Comment: Note: This will work only if you give it in parent div in IE (Not to the inner span inside div).

Comment: @Yves or `overflow-wrap: anywhere` works for me in table but not sure if everything else is same as wanted

Answer (score 176):

I am not sure about the browser compatibility

```css
word-break: break-all;
```

Also you can use the [`<wbr>`](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html) tag

> `<wbr>` (word break) means: "The browser
>   may insert a line break here, if it
>   wishes." It the browser does not think
>   a line break necessary nothing
>   happens.

Comment: Be aware of that word-break: break-all; will break words in the middle if it still can fit any characters on a line with other words before, which might not be desired outcome, while word-wrap: break-word; moves words to a new line and only breaks the word if it is too long to at all fit on it's own line in the container. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4AKhn/1/

Comment: break-all breaks everything. Okay to use with specific class which have long URL etc only, but not with BODY or P

Comment: This is definitely perfectly (and desired) acceptable when you are trying to display something like a request URI in a log table cell, and need it to stop breaking the whole table with a giant long cell. Breaking in the middle of a 'word' is wanted ;) While the accepted answer doesn't do squat in this regard.

Comment: @Skelly1983 there's no such thing as IE12

Comment: @TylerH I am aware of this, thanks for pointing this out to me after 3 years. This is listed on w3schools browser support chart for the wbr tag, which lists the support as "Internet Explorer/Edge" and has the version number listed as 12.0, which is in fact the first version of Edge.

Comment: @Skelly1983 So, no "IE12 and above" then... just Edge. BTW, Edge's first (public) version # was 20. EdgeHTML (now abandoned for Chromium) started at 12, however.

Answer (score 121):

This could be added to the accepted answer for a 'cross-browser' solution.

Sources:

- http://kenneth.io/blog/2012/03/04/word-wrapping-hypernation-using-css/
- http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/

```css
.your_element{
    -ms-word-break: break-all;
    word-break: break-all;

 /* Non standard for webkit */
     word-break: break-word;

    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
       -moz-hyphens: auto;
        -ms-hyphens: auto;
            hyphens: auto;
}
```

Comment: I got it on Chrome/Opera and Safari, but still didn't got it on Firefox and IE.
With this I solved Firefox, but IE is still going over the container (I have a long filename of just alpha-numeric characters).

Comment: Hi Kamafeather, i am not sure, but ifitisareallylongfilename you are attemting to break, the whole context (browser,html-css code) might be helpful to help you further more. Perhaps, you could create another question with your situation.

Comment: Please note that this breaks words in ungrammatical places.

Comment: @user1322720 what is an "ungrammatical" place?

Comment: This seems to be the best answer here. Don't break words when not needed.

Answer (score 37):

*I was just Googling the same issue, and posted my final solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20206221/195835).  It's relevant to this question too.*

You can do this easily with a div by giving it the style `word-wrap: break-word` (and you may need to set its width, too).

```css
div {
    word-wrap: break-word;         /* All browsers since IE 5.5+ */
    overflow-wrap: break-word;     /* Renamed property in CSS3 draft spec */
    width: 100%;
}
```

However, **for tables**, you also need to apply: `table-layout: fixed`.  This means the columns widths are no longer fluid, but are defined based on the widths of the columns in the first row only (or via specified widths). [Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout).

Sample code:

```css
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

table td {
    word-wrap: break-word;         /* All browsers since IE 5.5+ */
    overflow-wrap: break-word;     /* Renamed property in CSS3 draft spec */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for tables solution ;) However, I don't quite understand why break-word can't be used with auto layout. Any suggestion?

Comment: @ondObno Yeah I'm not sure of the technical reason, but several browsers appear to behave this way.  Perhaps it's because super long words mess with all the calculations required to determine the widths of each column.

Comment: Setting `width: 100%;` was the only way to get this working for me on FF and chrome!

Answer (score 30):

`&#8203;` is the HTML entity for a unicode character called the zero-width space (ZWSP) which is an invisible character which specifies a line-break opportunity.  Similarly the hyphen's purpose is to specify a line-break opportunity within a word boundary.

Comment: Very nice tip! Just for complementing: `&#8203;` has lower priority than a white-space (i.e. if there's one nearby, the line will break in a white-space instead).

Comment: Seems to be the `<wbr/>` unicode equivalent I was looking for

Answer (score 28):

Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks

```css
.pre-wrap {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

**DEMO**

```css
td {
   word-break: break-word;
   white-space: pre-wrap;
   -moz-white-space: pre-wrap;      
}

table {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><th>list</th>
<td>
1.longtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtext
2.breaklinebreaklinebreaklinebreaklinebreaklinebreaklinebreaklinebreaklinebreaklinebreaklinebreakline
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 25):

Found that using the following worked across most major browsers (Chrome, IE, Safari iOS/OSX) except Firefox (v50.0.2) when using flexbox and relying on `width: auto`.

```css
.your_element {
    word-wrap: break-word;   
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

Note: you may need to add browser vendor prefixes if you are not using an autoprefixer.

Another thing to watch out for is text using `&nbsp;` for spacing can cause line breaks mid-word.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. The other solutions didn't work with width: 100%. One thing to note: **word-break: break-word;** should be **word-break: break-all;**

Answer (score 8):

**CSS** `word-wrap:break-word;`, *tested in FireFox 3.6.3*

Answer (score 8):

Remove `white-space: nowrap`, if there is any.

Implement:

```
white-space: inherit;
word-break: break-word;
```

Comment: It solved a huge problem for me with the search result in Fomanti-UI (categoy>name)

Answer (score 4):

I solved my problem with code below.

```
display: table-caption;
```

Comment: This made a single letter appear on each line after the break for me.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in @davidcondrey's reply, there is not just the ZWSP, but also the SHY `&#173; &shy;` that can be used in very long, constructed words (think German or Dutch) that have to be broken on the spot **you** want it to be. 
Invisible, but it gives a hyphen the moment it's needed, thus keeping both word connected and line filled to the utmost.

That way the word *luchthavenpolitieagent* might be noted as `lucht&shy;haven&shy;politie&shy;agent` which gives longer parts than the syllables of the word.
Though I never read anything official about it, these soft hyphens manage to get higher priority in browsers than the official hyphens in the single words of the construct (***if*** they have some extension for it at all).
 In practice, no browser is capable of breaking such a long, constructed word by itself; on smaller screens resulting in a new line for it, or in some cases even a one-word-line (like when two of those constructed words follow up).

*FYI: it's Dutch for airport police officer*

Answer (score 4):

word-break: normal seems better to use than word-break: break-word because break-word breaks initials such as EN

```
word-break: normal
```

Answer (score 3):

First you should identify the width of your element. E.g:

```css
#sampleDiv{
  width: 80%;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="sampleDiv">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
```

so that when the text reaches the element width, it will be broken down into lines.

Answer (score 3):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap):

> The `overflow-wrap` CSS property specifies whether or not the browser should insert line breaks within words to prevent text from overflowing its content box.
>
> In contrast to `word-break`, `overflow-wrap` will only create a break if an entire word cannot be placed on its own line without overflowing.

So you can use:

```css
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

[Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=wordwrap)?

Answer (score 2):

```
.word-break {
   word-break: keep-all;
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked in Chrome, Firefox: `word-wrap: break-word`, `overflow-wrap: break-word` did not work for me. What works is either:

```
    overflow-wrap: anywhere;
```

or

```
    word-break: break-all;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can **use a grid system** for this.

```
<div class="container" style="background-color: green; width: 200px; height: 300px;">
   <div class="row">Thisisatest.Thisisatest.Thisisatest.</div>
   <div class="row">Thisisatest.Thisisatest.Thisisatest.</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Do this:

```
<div id="sampleDiv">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>

#sampleDiv{
   overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

just try this in our style

```
white-space: normal;
```

Comment: Duplicating answers across multiple questions is frowned-upon in *most* cases. In this case, it seems to be an incorrect answer to both questions. `normal` is the default `white-space` value. I think that adding it would have no effect on the example in the question. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: It depends on the override made by the CSS.
On my case, i had to redeclare it on "style" in my JSF component to override the default CSS style that was not "white-space: normal;"