# How do I wrap text with no whitespace inside a <td>?

Tags: css

I've used:

```css
word-break:break-all;
table-layout:fixed;
```

and the text wraps in Chrome but not Firefox.

Update: I decided to change the design so it didn't need the wrap; trying to sort out a CSS fix/hack was proving too frustrating and time consuming.

Answer (score 233):

Try this, I think this will work for something like "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG"
will produce

```
AARRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
RRGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
G
```

I have taken my example from a couple different websites on Google.  I have tested this on ff 5.0, IE 8.0, and Chrome 10.

```css
.wrapword {
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap;          /* Chrome & Safari */ 
    white-space: -pre-wrap;                 /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;               /* Opera 7 */
    white-space: pre-wrap;                  /* CSS3 */
    word-wrap: break-word;                  /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
    word-break: break-all;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<table style="table-layout:fixed; width:400px">
    <tr>
        <td class="wrapword">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ouch!! This will force breaking ANY word at arbitrary points even when not needed. Is there a workaround to have this break words ONLY when it's needed to not exceed the container's width? That is, to have it work the way "word-wrap: break-wird" is supposed to work in the first place if it wasn't buggy?

Comment: @matteo this answer worked better for me for that very reason: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18706058/234132

Comment: Force breaking problem can be solved with ``word-break: break-word;``

Comment: This was enough

word-wrap: break-word;

Answer (score 18):

Here is advanced version of what OP asked.

Sometimes, what happens is that, our client wants us to give '-' after word break to end of line.

Like

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBB
```

break to

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA-
BBBBBBBBB
```

So, there is new CSS property if supported, usually supported in latest browsers.

```css
.dont-break-out {

  /* These are technically the same, but use both */
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;

  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  /* This is the dangerous one in WebKit, as it breaks things wherever */
  word-break: break-all;
  /* Instead use this non-standard one: */
  word-break: break-word;

  /* Adds a hyphen where the word breaks, if supported (No Blink) */
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;

}
```

I am using this one.

I hope somebody will have demand like this.

Answer (score 14):

For an automatic table layout try to style the concerned td combining the attributes max-width and word-wrap.

Eg: `<td style="max-width:175px; word-wrap:break-word;"> ... </td>`

Tested in Firefox 32, Chrome 37 and  IE11.

Comment: I don't understand why, but it *only* works with `max-width`, and not with `width`. Nonetheless the best solution for me, because it doesn't break up words at arbitrary points.

Answer (score 4):

You can manually inject zero width spaces (&#8203;) to create break points.

Comment: There is also a non-standard HTML tag `<wbr>` [for "word break"].  Here is the browser support for this and the `&#8203;` solution: http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html

Answer (score 3):

Set a column width for the `td` tag.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was:

```
.output {

overflow-wrap: break-word;
word-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-word;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a long standing issue in Firefox, that harks back to Mozilla and Netscape.  I'll bet you were having the issue with the display of long URLs.  I think it is an issue with the rendering engine rather than something you can fix with CSS, without some ugly hacks.

Makes sense to change the design.

This looked hopeful though: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/word-wrap/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Angular for my project, and managed to solve this with a simple filter:

**Template:**

```
<td>{{string | wordBreak}}</td>
```

**Filter:**

```
app.filter('wordBreak', function() {
    return function(string) {
        return string.replace(/(.{1})/g, '$1​');
    }
})
```

---

You can't see it, but after `$1` there is an invisible space (thanks @kingjeffrey for the tip), which enabled word breaks for table cells.

Answer (score 0):

Another non-css solution that might be simpler is to put it in a read-only textbox. As far as I'm aware textboxes will wrap to a word if they can but if not they will just wrap anyway, and on no account will the contents ever spill over the edge of the containing object

Answer (score -1):

One slightly hackish way of doing this is by processing the text to add space between each letter. Replace spaces with `&nbsp;` Then use the letter-spacing css attribute to bring the spaces down.

I know, it's a hack... but if NOTHING else works, it should wrap without problem.

Comment: It's so hacky, so disrupting correct indexing and so hard to implement it shouldn't be an answer at all :-)