# Any way to keep a word wrapped querystring link from losing it's click function?

Tags: asp.net, .net, url, query-string, word-wrap

I have a really long link that I need to display on an .aspx page. I word wrapped it because it was escaping the parent container. I used css similar to this: [Word wrap a link so it doesn't overflow its parent div width.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241369/word-wrap-a-link-so-it-doesnt-overflow-its-parent-div-width)   It works fine, but now the link isn't clickable(blue) anymore. Is there a quick and clean way to have the link maintain its link?

I figure I can just put an `a href='the same reallyreallylong ?querystringurl'` around it, but it seems messy.

EDIT: Now I'm starting to think I was hallucinating and the page never displayed the link as a clickable url. I'm going to put the 'a' tag around it. Code edit:

```
<li>Example:<p class="wordwrap">http://www.blah.com/yup.asmx?quuuuuuuuuuueeery</p></li>
```

CSS:

```
.wordwrap
{
white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */    
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */    
white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */    
word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to display the url as a link then an anchor tag is the way to go.

```
<a href="url">url</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted to get a little more complicated you could always call a url shortner api like tinyUrl and display the shortened url instead.

ex. http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=http://thisismyreallylongurl.com