# Anchor tag text won't wrap

Tags: html, overflow, anchor

Having a simple problem. I have anchor tags that are links to external websites, which are underneath a p element, inside a 12 column grid. I have used col-4 on them, the text is staying within the container but the anchors text is not breaking onto another line. The p element and its text keeps to the col-4, but the anchor text overflows. Please help

HTML

```
<div class="grouped-content__selection">
<div class="col4">
    <h3>Go Kart Sorihuela Costa</h3>    
    <p>Hello <br>Website: <a href="google.co.uk">This line of text goes over</a></p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.grouped-content__selection {
border-top: 2px solid #184450;
padding: 2rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
overflow: hidden;
height: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think `a{white-space: pre-wrap}` should do the trick

here is a link to a  [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241369/word-wrap-a-link-so-it-doesnt-overflow-its-parent-div-width)

Comment: cheers for the response. I tried that but all it did was cut the text off. I have gone for the easy route and used a button instead. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a "display: contents" style to < a > tag.

inline:

```
<p>Hello <br>Website: <a href="google.co.uk" style="display: contents">This line of text goes over</a></p>
```

external:

```
<p>Hello <br>Website: <a href="google.co.uk" class="align-link">This line of text goes over</a></p>
```

css file:

```
.align-link{
  display: contents;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`a { word-wrap: break-word; }` worked for me, thanks to [this link](https://forums.asp.net/post/5462917.aspx)