# How to wrap continuous text without spaces?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS: How do I wrap text with no whitespace inside a <td>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247358/css-how-do-i-wrap-text-with-no-whitespace-inside-a-td)

I have a line of text that is hundreds of characters long, and that I
need to display on a page.

Because the line is continuous with no spaces, the browser won't wrap
the text. My goal is to have the text wrap according to the size of
the browser window.

Anyone know how to do this using CSS?

Example code:

```
<html>
<body>
 <table> <tr><td>
   mffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</td>      </tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 16):

With this css

`word-break: break-all;`

you get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
word-wrap: break-all;
```

Comment: word-wrap: break-work; is not working it is only wrapping words

Comment: @Praveena sorry updated answer