# Move to newline when tabbing/spacing to end of contenteditable div

Tags: html, css, angular

Recently I have been having a few issues with using a content editable div as a text box for a project I have been working on. The project is built with Angular2 on the front-end.

The issue I have been having is when I go to tab/space all the way to the end of the content editable div, rather than moving to the next line, it instead keeps adding tabs that appear to accumulate in the text content of the div. By that I mean, if I hit the tab/space key 4 times once it reaches the end, I will then have to backspace 4 times to clear them out.

```
<div class="text-box" contenteditable="true"></div>

body
{
  background-color: black;
}

.text-box
{
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YxYNYW

The code pen I included demonstrates the issue. If you just click inside the box and then hold space bar, once the cursor gets to the end, it will not move to a newline. I realize it has something to do with the white-space: pre-wrap property I use with the content editable div. Is there anyway to get this to work while still being able to use that property?

I would like to keep the pre-wrap property because it preserves all the white-space that is brought in from objects with text in the database. I tried it with the pre-line property over pre-wrap but that caused the text to jump when clicking into the editable div. I also tried using word-break: break-all which seemed to work but then the text gets a little messed up.

Also on a side note, has anyone ever experienced an issue where they were unable to click between characters once the text was highlighted? This is kind of a weird issue to describe, and a tough one to track down apparently. What happens is I will type some text into the div, highlight it with my cursor, and then if I try to deselect the text by clicking in between characters, it will not work. I will have to click a line that is currently not highlighted or outside of the element entirely to deselect any highlighted text.

I originally thought maybe it was a content editable issue, but it seems to be working fine in the code pen I linked, so now I am not sure what it is.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: did you try adding "word-wrap: break-word;"?

Comment: @Jehoshuah I did try using word-wrap: break-word and was, unfortunately, still having the same problem. I think I tried every word wrap property and could not get any of them to work. 

An answer below says to use word-break: break-all which does fix the issue, but it also breaks all the words when they get to the end of the container, which I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use word-break for solving your issue.Modify your css like following

```
body
{
  background-color: black;
}



  .text-box
{
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  height: 200px;
  width:150px;
  margin: auto;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
     white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
     white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
     white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
     word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
     word-break: break-word;
     white-space: normal;
}
```

This solves your problem.Here is the working pen [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VzygbV)

Please reffer [this ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135962/split-text-into-the-next-line-if-content-exceeds-the-fixed-width-for-html-table?answertab=active#tab-top) for more info

Comment: This does fix the issue with tabs/spaces not breaking to a newline, but it also breaks words when they get to the end of the container, which I was hoping to avoid.  Is there anyway to use the white-space: pre-wrap and word-break: break-word properties together while also having tabs/spaces break to a newline when they reach the end of the container?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. By using pre-wrap and break-word together, I get the same problem as before where spacing to the end of the container does not break to a newline. While using 'white-space: pre-line' seems to work, if I select text inside a content editable div with the pre-line property, it causes it to jump. I am trying to find a way to continue using pre-wrap and break-word together, but to also force the space character to jump to a new line when it reaches the end of a container.

Comment: That did the trick! What's weird about that solution, though, is if you switch around 'white-space: pre-wrap' and 'white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important' it no longer works. Thanks for the answer!