# two DIVS, one fluid, one fixed, fixed div regardless of height has vertically centered element inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is as far as I got. So far I am unable to vertically centre the icon in the right DIV regardless of the height. I am also unable to get the text in the left DIV to break when it hits it's max length.

Here is what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/SpSjL/1685/

**both boxes should remain the same height, if there are a few lines of text in the left, the right should adjust as well**

expected: [image]

HTML:

```
  <div class="container">

    <div class="right">
        <div class="someIcon"></div>
    </div> 
    <div class="left">
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccdcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccdccccccccddccccc
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .left {
    overflow: hidden;

    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    /* word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
    text-wrap: normal; 
    white-space: normal;*/
    word-break: break-all;
}

.container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.someIcon {
    background: url(http://www.adiumxtras.com/images/thumbs/adiumtwit_twitters_icon_for_adium_1_31971_7892_thumb.png);
    background-size: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%:
}

.right {
    float: right;
    width: 50px;
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    display:table-cell; 
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: How about for icon centering: http://jsfiddle.net/SpSjL/1686/ (replace -webkit-transform with cross-browser transform implementation).

Comment: Can you please make it clearer what you are trying to achieve? JSfiddle doesn't really help.

Comment: @AndreiNemes eveo added an image to the post that shows the goal.

Comment: You have a colon (not a semi-colon) after `top: 50%`

Comment: Was able to center icon with jquery and removing absolute position http://jsfiddle.net/SpSjL/1691/

Comment: How has everyone gotten this wrong so far? Nobodies right icon DIV stretches vertically, aligning with the red box. Yet to find a useable answer...

Comment: I know they say don't use tables unless you have tabular data, but have you considered trying that as a temporary hack? That should enable you to make the two sections the same height. See this for help on making them expand height together: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-divs-that-are-side-by-side-the-same-height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simplified your layout by using the background properties position attributes to keep it centered vertically and to the right. You shouldn't need to do any floating. I try and keep my layouts as simple as possible.

CSS

```
.container {
    border:1px solid black;
    background: url(http://www.adiumxtras.com/images/thumbs/adiumtwit_twitters_icon_for_adium_1_31971_7892_thumb.png) center right 15px no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 15px 75px 15px 15px;
}
```

wrapword class pulled from [CSS: How do I wrap text with no whitespace inside a <td>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247358/css-how-do-i-wrap-text-with-no-whitespace-inside-a-td)

```
.wrapword{
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
word-break: break-all;
white-space: normal;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container wrapword">
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>

<div class="container wrapword">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet facilisis tellus. Aliquam eu mi in augue faucibus egestas sed convallis lorem. Nulla rutrum purus ac dolor dictum viverra.
</div>

<div class="container wrapword">
    a short sentence
</div>
```

**update**: removed unecessary div, support for one really long word (although I imagine that isn't necessary) 
http://jsfiddle.net/SpSjL/1708/

you can adjust the padding on the background and the container to fit your image.

Comment: Why did I not think of that? Genius, works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, had to give someone else the green mark due to needing this to work with fontawesome. http://jsfiddle.net/SpSjL/1710/

Comment: Any way to make the arrow float to the right all the time while remaining inside the parent div? http://jsfiddle.net/SpSjL/1712/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SpSjL/1713/ I'd advise against using table cells for layout unless you're actually working with tables.

Comment: Wow, why didn't I think of that? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

**First, the icon, it's quite simple** :

Remove the .someIcon element, and put the icon as a centered background of the .right div :

```
.right {


   background: url(http://www.adiumxtras.com/images/thumbs/adiumtwit_twitters_icon_for_adium_1_31971_7892_thumb.png) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px;
    float: right;
    width: 50px;
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    display:table-cell; 
    vertical-align:middle;
    }

The layout problem needs more time, I come with that soon.
```

EDIT :

Here you go :), **working demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/SpSjL/1709/

You have to use display: table cell; on both divs :

```
    <div class="container">


        <div class="left">
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccdcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccdccccccccddccccc
        </div>
         <div class="right">
            <div class="someIcon"></div>
        </div> 
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS :

```
.left {
display: table-cell;
    margin-right: 52px;
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    /* word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
    text-wrap: normal; 
    white-space: normal;*/
    word-break: break-all;

}

.container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
}



.right {
     background: url(http://www.adiumxtras.com/images/thumbs/adiumtwit_twitters_icon_for_adium_1_31971_7892_thumb.png) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50px;
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;

}
```

And I cleaned up all your code.

Comment: This doesn't seem to keep the div with the icon aligned to the right; it pushes it to a new line of the left div gets too big

Comment: Sorry, I didn't update the fiddle : here it is > http://jsfiddle.net/SpSjL/1709/ (and I updated my answer)

Answer (score 1):

check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/SpSjL/1702/)

Simply remove `float` from your right div, and place it after the left div.

**Updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/SpSjL/1705/)  with minimal CSS**

Comment: The boxes do not stretch dynamically, they have a fixed height. They must both depend on the amount of text in the left.

Comment: @eveo well, it does stretch, check by adding/remove content to the div.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but can you make the icon centered horizontally within the div as well as vertically?

Comment: @TylerH it's done in the updated fiddle.. plz check the second fiddle

Comment: Actually, it should remain 100% width if the text is short too...http://jsfiddle.net/SpSjL/1712/

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you know your icon is always going to be fixed in size, and you are willing to resort to absolute positioning, what's stopping you from using the negative margins?

```
.someIcon {
    background: url(http://www.adiumxtras.com/images/thumbs/adiumtwit_twitters_icon_for_adium_1_31971_7892_thumb.png);
    background-size: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: -10px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpSjL/1687/).

Comment: No, everyone so far has made this error. Both boxes do not stretch based on the left one. They must both be the exact same height, with vertically positioned elements within.