# div overflow hidden but to parent width

Tags: css, overflow

Regarding the following:

```
<div style='text-align: center'>
<div style='position: absolute; left: 50%; text-align: left'>
    <div style='position: relative; left: -50%; background-color: #cc0;'>
        ThisShouldBeDisplayedAsNormal
        <div style='overflow: hidden'>
            ButThisIWantToBeClippetAboutHereButItIsNot
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/em4v0v8h/1/

I want the inner div content to be clipped to the parent. If I explicitly set a width in the inner div like width: 275px, the inner div content is clipped as desired. But is there a way to use the parent width?

Comment: Probably no way without specifying an explicit `width` for the inner div or the parent.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247358/css-how-do-i-wrap-text-with-no-whitespace-inside-a-td

Comment: @kul_mi I'm not sure if that help because that's totally a different issue and it needs the width to be specified.

Comment: no, the width is specified just for the parent div

Comment: @kul_mi the OP haven't specified any width for any element.