# Problems with the width of the columns <TD> -Xslt 1.0-

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-1.0

I created a simple table to give a good view of my data.

**The problem is created by field LIGHT_EXCEPTION, it not contains space**, the content is very long and unfortunately I lose formatted table because i am not able to control the width of column. If I insert a space into LIGHT_ EXCEPTION the system control this case and I not lost the format table column.

Question: there is an alternative mothod to control this case?

I want that the column size table is fixed and when arrive at the end column  continue to the next line automatically.

[image]

You can see in this attachments that the last column (8 column) is shifted to left. I want that if content is too long go to the next line automatically to continue the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [CSS specifications, §17.3 Columns](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#columns):

> **'width'**
>      The 'width' property gives the minimum width for the column.

So, if the text inside a column is particularly long, the table width algorithm can decide to make the column larger than its `width` property.

If you want to set a **fixed width** for the whole table, **use `width` on the `table` element**; for example:

```
<table style="width:12cm">
    <tr style="...">
        ...
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: the problem is that the field  LIGHT_EXCEPTION not contains space and cannot go to the next line or manage new line. There is a method to control this case?

Comment: Understood, so [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3247358/4453460) should help you.