# text overflowing inside of a div

Tags: html

I have a nested div. I want to show text inside description but the problem is , text goes outside div. I want to go into the new line(like `<br/>`) and shows all text.
I don't want to use overflow:hidden.

```
<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-8" id="showPos" style="height: 295px;">
                                <script>
                                    $(document).ready(function(){
                                        showPosition(<?php echo $results['lat']; ?>,<?php echo $results['lon'];?>);
                                    });
                                </script>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4" >
                                   <div class="well">
                                       <div class="row">
                                           <div class="col-lg-5"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Title</div><div class="col-lg-7">bad hurricane</div>
                                       </div><hr />
                                       <div class="row">
                                           <div class="col-lg-5"><i class="fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true"></i> Description</div><div class="col-lg-7"> dflsfljdlfsdfsfldksfslsjffldfjjffjdslkfsdfjdljdslffjfjfjfjfdklfjsfjj</div>
                                       </div><hr />
                                       <div class="row">
                                           <div class="col-lg-3"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i><h6>10</h6></div>
                                           <div class="col-lg-3"><i class="fa fa-road" aria-hidden="true"></i><h6>10</h6></div>
                                           <div class="col-lg-3"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i><h6>10</h6></div>
                                       </div>
                                   </div>
                               </div>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following after, should help you on the way:

[CSS: How do I wrap text with no whitespace inside a <td>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247358/css-how-do-i-wrap-text-with-no-whitespace-inside-a-td)

Answer (score 0):

Just Add "word-wrap:break-word;" style in your div as below:

```
<div class="col-lg-7" style="word-wrap:break-word"> dflsfljdlfsdfsfldksfslsjffldfjjffjdslkfsdfjdljdslffjfjfjfjfdklfjsfjj</div>
                                       </div><hr />
```