# overflow:hidden not working in colgroups for very long cells

Tags: html, css, html-table, word-wrap, colgroup

I have searched for quite a bit in stackoverflow and google. But failed to find a solution.
I have a 11 column table, of which the first column can get long text (without spaces). I have adapted to colgroup approach but it is not working for me.

```css
.mytable {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 1000px;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
}

.ten {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.others {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<table border=1 class="mytable">

  <colgroup>
    <col class="ten" />
    <col class="others" />
    <col class="others" />
    <col class="others" />
    <col class="others" />
    <col class="others" />
    <col class="others" />
    <col class="others" />
    <col class="others" />
    <col class="others" />
    <col class="others" />
  </colgroup>

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>VERY LONG COLUMN</th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>G</th>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>I</th>
      <th>J</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</td>
      <td>not so long</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</td>
      <td>not so long</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</td>
      <td>not so long</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</td>
      <td>not so long</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</td>
      <td>not so long</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: table output]

I need to have a fixed width table. And I am looking for a solution where i can wrap the text. I tried with `word-wrap: break-word;` but it gives me the exact output.
Any help is much appreciated.

Solutions I have tried:

[Word-wrap in an HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-an-html-table)

[how-do-i-wrap-text-with-no-whitespace-inside-a-td](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247358/how-do-i-wrap-text-with-no-whitespace-inside-a-td)

Comment: Class `ten` is not a applied to the long cells.

Comment: It has to be applied to cells, col can only take background, width, visibility & borders : https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/tables.html#columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `word-wrap: break-all` instead:

```css
.mytable {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 1000px;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.ten {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.others {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<table border=1 class="mytable">

  <colgroup>
    <col class="ten" />
    <col class="others" />
    <col class="others" />
    <col class="others" />
    <col class="others" />
    <col class="others" />
    <col class="others" />
    <col class="others" />
    <col class="others" />
    <col class="others" />
    <col class="others" />
  </colgroup>

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>VERY LONG COLUMN</th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>G</th>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>I</th>
      <th>J</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</td>
      <td>not so long</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</td>
      <td>not so long</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</td>
      <td>not so long</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</td>
      <td>not so long</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</td>
      <td>not so long</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<colgroup>` element can only apply the following style properties (see [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/tables.html#columns)) to the `<td>` elements:

- border
- background
- width
- visibility

In this case, you can use the `:first-child` pseudo-selector to limit the overflow of the first `<td>` element of each row.

```css
.mytable {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 1000px;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
}

.ten {
  width: 100px;
}

td:first-child {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.others {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<table border=1 class="mytable">

  <colgroup>
    <col class="ten" />
    <col class="others" />
    <col class="others" />
    <col class="others" />
    <col class="others" />
    <col class="others" />
    <col class="others" />
    <col class="others" />
    <col class="others" />
    <col class="others" />
    <col class="others" />
  </colgroup>

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>VERY LONG COLUMN</th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>G</th>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>I</th>
      <th>J</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</td>
      <td>not so long</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</td>
      <td>not so long</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</td>
      <td>not so long</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</td>
      <td>not so long</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</td>
      <td>not so long</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
      <td>small</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong: if I want text wrapping, then i need to write td:*-child for each one (or the ones I want).

Comment: You can always apply them to all td's (like the accepted answer), or use `td:nth-child()` to apply it to a specific column.