# Set html TD width to number of characters

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to set the TD width to number of characters, for ex, if I set to 11, only 11 characters must be displayed and rest must be in a new row. I tried width property but it displays differently in different browsers/resolutions.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
<td>test1</td>
<td>CRTAX_G</td>
    <td>
    28-FEB-2013, 11-MAR-2013, 13-MAR-2013
    </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td>test1</td>
<td>CRTAX_G</td>
    <td>
    28-FEB-2013, 11-MAR-2013, 13-MAR-2013
    </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td>test1</td>
<td>CRTAX_G</td>
    <td>
    28-FEB-2013, 04-MAR-2013, 05-MAR-2013, 07-MAR-2013, 11-MAR-2013, 13-MAR-2013, 12-MAR-2013, 08-MAR-2013, 06-MAR-2013
    </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td>test1</td>
<td>CRTAX_G</td>
    <td>
    28-FEB-2013, 11-MAR-2013, 13-MAR-2013
    </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td>test1</td>
<td>CRTAX_G</td>
    <td>
    28-FEB-2013, 06-MAR-2013, 08-MAR-2013, 12-MAR-2013, 13-MAR-2013, 11-MAR-2013, 07-MAR-2013, 05-MAR-2013, 01-MAR-2013
    </td>
    </tr>
    <table>
```

which displays the dates in the table in a single line as,

```
28-FEB-2013, 06-MAR-2013, 08-MAR-2013, 12-MAR-2013,
```

I want it to be displayed as

```
   28-FEB-2013,
   11-MAR-2013,
   13-MAR-2013,
```

every date must be in a new line.

Comment: The contents of the TD looks like a list of dates to me. Why not declare a OL or UL and style the items? That way you don't have to treat is as unstructured text, but you create structure and style it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution i can imagine is that:

```
table tr td+td+td {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 8em;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/elaleg/1/edit

Comment: It works. Is there anyway not to use monospace font and get the same result?

Comment: I thing that using monospace is obligatory - if you want do it without changing content.

Comment: It would seem that em is the height of a character, not the width.  You should use ch instead.  See the second answer down here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186457/specify-width-in-characters

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your text in  tag or anything else with following style:

```
display: inline-block; width: 11em;
```

Check [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kbxvG/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
 <body>
   <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:103px;word-wrap:break-word;">28-FEB-2013, 11-MAR-2013, 13-MAR-2013</td>
    </tr>
</table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Try this, I'm hoping you'll get the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6843437/1371631)

or try css style white- space effectively

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one solution which worked for me.
Assuming that td has a class name (say payerName) specified and the table has an id (say sortable).

```
$(".payerName").css({"white-space":"nowrap"});
$(".payerName").css({"overflow":"hidden"});
$(".payerName").css({"text-overflow":"ellipsis"});
$("#sortable").css("table-layout","fixed");
```

This is a set of steps you can use to avoid long length strings into the td. 
the ellipsis property will add a '...' at the end of the string/value.
You can add the title attribute so that it displays the actual value when mouse is hover.

Hope this helps!