# How to break a long word in a table TD element?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Here I have a table in which I want to break a long word into multiple lines by changing its cell width (e.g. as 20px), like below:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tbody>
            <tr >
                <td>
                123
                </td>
                <td>123</td>
                <td style="width: 20px;">
                    canyouhelpmebreakintolineswith20pxwidth?</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                abc
                </td>
                <td>
                def
                </td>
                <td style="width: 20px;">
                placeholder
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {border-collapse:collapse; table-layout:fixed;}
table td {
  border-width: 1px;
  border:solid 1px; 
  word-wrap:break-word;}
```

I even made the width of the whole columns as 20 px, and I used table-layout as fixed and word-wrap as break-word, but the cell width still refused to change. Can you please point me where I am wrong?

Below is the JS Fiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/flyingbee2012/nxzjof9d/21/

Comment: Set a max-width on the td. e.g. max-width: 20px;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [force line break in html table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843412/force-line-break-in-html-table-cell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to implement the solution described here:
[force line break in html table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843412/force-line-break-in-html-table-cell)
If you want to automatically wrap a word then you have to add the width of the table itself. In your case set the width of the table to 100% to create equal sized columns that automatically wrap. I prepared a small example with 80% width and the 20px column [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pgbhqonm/).

```
<html>
<body>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tbody>
            <tr >
                <td>
                123
                </td>
                <td>123</td>
                <td style="width: 20px">
                    canyouhelpmebreakintolineswith20pxwidth?</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                abc
                </td>
                <td>
                def
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

And the css:

```
table {border-collapse:collapse; table-layout:fixed; width: 80%}
table td {
  border-width: 1px;
  border:solid 1px; 
  word-wrap:break-word;}
```

Comment: Thanks Marius. That seems work. I am just wondering if it is possible to set the table width flexibly while being able to resize its individual cell. Interestingly, it would work if I use  word-break:break-word like Joseph mentioned; but this is not supported with browsers such as IE.

Answer (score 2):

Your property is incorrect.  You appear to be trying to use an old Microsoft CSS property that is since removed.

> The property was originally a nonstandard and unprefixed Microsoft extension called word-wrap, and was implemented by most browsers with the same name. It has since been renamed to overflow-wrap, with word-wrap being an alias. - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap)

The comparable modern property would either be `overflow-wrap: anywhere` or `word-break: break-word`.  I'm not familiar enough with the differences between the two, but [MDN has a nice breakdown of the related properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap#comparing_overflow-wrap_word-break_and_hyphens) (scroll to "Result" to see it in action).