# Line-height in div not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I have a div within which I put paragraphs of text, images, links etc., I am unable to use the line height property. I retrieve this content from my database using PHP.

A typical scenario would be,

```
<div class = "story">
Now there are many complaints. We will study the matter... Whether there is a need for a separate policy or some kind of clarification is needed, we will make it clear soon

Now there are many complaints. We will study the matter... Whether there is a need for a separate policy or some kind of clarification is needed, we will make it clear soon
</div>

.story{
   line-height: 200px;
}
```

I type in the content into a  and it is stored in a db. Now I observe that where ever I physically ended my line by pressing enter I get a gap of 200 px. Not between the lines. Based on the screen resolution and other things a line could end anywhere right?

however it is working something like this,

[image]

Edit 1: Yes I have tried word-wrap: break-word it doesn't work.

Comment: Didn't understand the question, but you can always use the width property to limit the width of the div element. Also it should be <br/> not </br>.

Comment: Your question makes no sense.

Comment: Is this because you are using `line-height` to vertically position your block of text? If so, you are addressing the wrong issue.

Comment: Sentence breaks are usually accomplished with the `<br />` tag. Your title refers to breaking a sentence, yet your question itself makes little sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force a line break in a loooooong word in a DIV?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058866/how-to-force-a-line-break-in-a-loooooong-word-in-a-div)

Comment: You should also use proper text tags instead of bare text nodes (as shown) and not use break tags for spacing. That's what margin/padding is for.

Comment: I don't use break tags for spacing. I have a <textarea> where I type the text it, gets stored in a DB, I retrieve it and display it using a div whose width is 800px. @Paulie_D

Answer (score 1):

You can use this if you want to break the sentence and then line-height might work

```
 .story{
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Tried it man. Doesn't work. I edited the question, please look at it again.

Answer (score 0):

The line isn't breaking because you're using the wrong tag i.e. `</br>`. You need to use a `<br/>` tag to add a line break: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bLq54ytg/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class = "story">
    Now there are many complaints. We will<br/> study the matter... Whether there is a need for a<br/> separate policy or some kind of clarification is needed,<br/> we will make it clear soon 
</div>
```