# How to keep the text inside the div?

Tags: html, css

I have a page that shows text retrieved from a mysql database.

I can't figure out why I cannot get the text to display as a block of text within the div. Instead it overflows the div. (I'm using bootstrap 3) Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/ha2pnrhz/)

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <!---MAIN COLUMN------>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-lg-6 col-centered">
      <h2>
        How to keep the text inside the div?
      </h2>

      <div class="mytext">
        fdsnkfhskghkgskghsdkghdskghdsklhgkdlsghds
        khgkdshgdksghdsklghdskg hkdslhgkdshgkdshgkdshgkd
        shgksdlhgksdhgkdslhgkdshgkdshgkdshgksd hgkldshgkd
        shgkldshgkhdsgkhdskghdskhgkdlshgkdshgkldsh
        gkdshgklhds kghdskghdskl
        <small>
        </small>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force a line break in a loooooong word in a DIV?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058866/how-to-force-a-line-break-in-a-loooooong-word-in-a-div)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Used `word-break:break-all;` to break the word

```css
.mytext{
  word-break:break-all;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <!---MAIN COLUMN------>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-lg-6 col-centered">
      <h2>
        How to keep the text inside the div?
      </h2>

      <div class="mytext">
        fdsnkfhskghkgskghsdkghdskghdsklhgkdlsghds
        khgkdshgdksghdsklghdskg hkdslhgkdshgkdshgkdshgkd
        shgksdlhgksdhgkdslhgkdshgkdshgkdshgksd hgkldshgkd
        shgkldshgkhdsgkhdskghdskhgkdlshgkdshgkldsh
        gkdshgklhds kghdskghdskl
        <small>
        </small>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

give CSS to

```
.mytext{
  width:200px;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  border:thin black solid;
}
```

Here is updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ha2pnrhz/2/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a purely hypothetical question - on a real website you will have real Text consisting of real words which are much shorter than your example phantasy word/s, and they will fit nicely into that div since the text will be broken at word ends, i.e. spaces. Just use Same real text and you'll see.