# How to go new line when table cell characters reached 10 charachers in html

Tags: html

I don't know how to go  new line with limited characters.
Help me!

```html
<table >
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Name</th> 
    <th>Comment</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2017/08/25</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
  <td>commentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcomment</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you want to create a line break?

Comment: You want the <td> to break every 10 chars ? So it's be 
commentcom<br/>
mentcommen<br/>
tcommentcom<br/>
mentcomment<br/>
commentcomm<br/>
entcomment

?

Comment: I'm sure you could easily have found the answer by typing your question's title in google ... [try that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058866/how-to-force-a-line-break-in-a-loooooong-word-in-a-div)

Comment: Yes,I want the <td> to break every 10 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<table >
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Name</th> 
    <th>Comment</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2017/08/25</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
  <td style="word-break: break-all">commentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcomment</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Use `word-break:break-all;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [`overflow-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) or [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)

Use them as follow, in your css:

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
// Or
word-break: break-all;
```

note about `word-wrap`: if you see it in other answers, keep in mind that it is just the "old name" for `overflow-wrap` that dates back to before `word-wrap` became the official, standardized name. They should have the exact same comportment.