# CSS Overflow issue with no spaced text

Tags: html, css, overflow

how i can solve that problem?:

[My problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq882.png)

if I put a spaced text there is no problem, but otherwise...

Im using materializecss if it can help :)

Comment: where is your code...

Comment: I do not have code because I do not know how to start fixing it

Comment: Try this in your CSS tag for the element in question: ` word-wrap: break-word;`

Comment: Perfect Brad :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force a line break in a loooooong word in a DIV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058866/how-to-force-a-line-break-in-a-loooooong-word-in-a-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your CSS tag for the element in question: `word-wrap: break-word;`

Answer from: Brad Colacino

Answer (score 0):

As Brad mentioned, the reason why your text flies off the div is because the long single line counts as a single word. By default, lines are divided by spaces and other non-word delimiters.

To fix this case where a long word runs off the screen, use this:

`div {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}`

This will tell the browser to divide the word at the point where it runs off the div (assuming it is a div) and start a new line continuing where the word was cut off like :

`abcdef
ghijk`...

EDIT: If you are using CSS3, there is also [word-break](https://justmarkup.com/log/2015/07/dealing-with-long-words-in-css/)