# word-wrap: break word; fix or alternative

Tags: javascript, html, css, word-wrap

With **word-wrap: break-word;** if the word is going to break anyway, I dont want a line-break first, it is useless and ugly. How to avoid that?

**Example:**

Given a div with **word-wrap: break-word;** and a width equivalent to those 23 "x" characters like so: 
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

The div innerHTML is "xx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" like so:

```
<div>xx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</div>
```

This is how the innerHTML of the div is displayed vs how it is wanted respecting the 23 "x" width.

**What happens:** 
xx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxx

**What I want:**
xx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx

**word-break: break-all;** and similar or more recent attributes are not a solution to the problem. I dont want words that can avoid breaking to break. I only want words with a width superior than the container width to break BUT without line-break first like with **word-wrap: break-word;** because it is simply useless and ugly.

Comment: something like `word-break: break-all ;` ?

Comment: With pure CSS, I don't think you can, but I'm happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force a line break in a long word in a DIV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058866/how-to-force-a-line-break-in-a-long-word-in-a-div)

Comment: @Thomas - Ok. I just want to precise that answers without pure CSS are also accepted.

Comment: @Sfili_81 Sorry I confused word-break: break-all ; and word-break: break-word ; in my last comment (deleted). But word-break: break-all ; is systematically breaking words. I dont want that either. I want words that are going to break any way to break without line-break first and words that can avoid breaking to line break.

Comment: `word-break` is deprecated, now it's `overflow-wrap`

Comment: Regarding edit 2, I removed it because it would also break words that normally wouldn't have to be broken -> no better than break-all...

Comment: Is the person that closed the topic can clarify what is missing? the code to reproduce the behavior is word-wrap: break-word; The problem is that it is line-breaking for no reason when word is too big anyway.

Comment: I dont understand why my question is closed. I think people like @Thomas understood it at first sight and some less experienced users throwed easy bad answers that led to think that my question was not clear. Is it closed by a bot?

Comment: As @Flash has suggested, `overflow-wrap: break-word;` does what you want it to do (see the note in the [Mozilla spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap#content)).

Comment: @JamesWhiteley I tested it in chrome and it has the same behavior as word-wrap: break-word; so its not solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sfili_81 mentionned it

> something like `word-break: break-all;`

Here you go

```js
var txt = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;

var dataArr = txt.split(' ');

var paragraph = document.getElementById("demo");
var finalString = "";
for (var i = 0; i < dataArr.length; i++){
    if (dataArr[i].length > 6 ) {
      finalString = finalString + " <span>"+ dataArr[i]+"</span>"; 
  }
  else{
    finalString = finalString + " " + dataArr[i];
  }
}

paragraph.innerHTML = finalString;
```

```css
div{
  width:50px;
  background: red;
 
}
span{
  word-break:break-all;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">test teeeeeeeeeeest test test test</div>
```

PS: I still flagged the question as duplicate from: [How to force a line break in a long word in a DIV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058866/how-to-force-a-line-break-in-a-long-word-in-a-div)

**EDIT**

As `break-all` is also breaking the whole text / word and `break-word` is letting a white space / gap before the long word, then it is not adapting. So only solution is JS. In this example, We are injecting span element to text with length over 6.

Comment: word-break: break-all ; is systematically breaking words. I want words that are going to break any way to break without line-break first and words that can avoid breaking to line break. –

Comment: @111111111111 Here you go with JS solution

Comment: JavaScript is completely unnecessary - this can be done with simple CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/fz63oyra/

Comment: @James Whiteley No it is not. Look in your fiddle how the second word line-break and break after INSTEAD of just breaking straight away. This is exactly what I say I don't want in my question.

Comment: @MaxiGui I dont think there is a better way. I'm curious why it is not the default behavior of word-wrap: break-word, i find that it is obviously more elegant without line-break.

Answer (score 1):

<s>In complement of the answer of MaxiGui. You can also use non-breaking space `&nbsp;` in your HTML (or replace space with non-breaking space with JS).
But I think it's better to use of `word-break: break-all;`</s>

EDIT : hyphens do all the job https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens

Comment: word-break: break-all ; is systematically breaking words. I want words that are going to break anyway to break without line-break first and words that can avoid breaking to line break.

Comment: Then you can replace the space just before your long word by a non-breaking space &nbsp;. May be with JS you can detect this words and do the replacement automatically

Comment: Probably the way to go. I have a chat log box with a resizable width. It means to create an array of the words in each log and to verify the size of each word then remove or add &nbsp; in front

Comment: This won't scale with different screen sizes/mobile; it'll only look correct on the size monitor you write it in.

Comment: Not if your relaunch the JS at each size modification

Comment: In fact, with a small research, I find hyphens https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens . It will do all you need

Comment: @Léo It would be perfect if we find a way to hide the hyphen.

Comment: Not really the best solution, check the browser compatibility. This is why I did not even offered it.

Comment: @MaxiGui you are right. Also it seems to only fit the question requirement in the first exemple of the mozilla page.

Comment: Hyphens seems to be supported by all browser for English. If another language, then it might not work

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution using jQuery:

HTML:

```
<div id="demo">xx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var words = $('#demo').text().split(' ');
  $('#demo').empty();
  $.each(words, function(i, v) {
    $('#demo').append($('<span>').text(v));
  })
});
```

CSS:

```
#demo {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #F00;
  word-wrap: wrap;
  word-break: break-all;
}

#demo span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px dashed #00F;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin-right: 2px; /* add the space back */
}
```

This solution is slightly better than the accepted one, as it does not require a hardcoded value of the words' length.

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/shivanraptor/4eagkyb7/16/)

Comment: The behavior of your demo is the same as word-wrap: break-word. Look how the third long word is line-breaking before breaking. The question is about avoiding this line-breaking.