# html css force break text line

Tags: css, line-breaks

As I search many answers I found excellent solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058866/how-to-force-a-line-break-in-a-long-word-in-a-div). All was check.

```
table {
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%;
}
div.some_container{
        overflow-wrap: anywhere;   /* modern CSS3 property */
        word-wrap: break-word;     /* deprecated All browsers since IE 5.5+ */
}
```

Very useful is table-layout it makes browser to [faster render table](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp) and prevents change of the width of table cells etc from content. overflow-wrap prevents additionally and full.

Comment: Is there a problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: No I post for points to can answer  to other posts or vote it. I have no reputation etc and could share with me knowledge.
I'm known programmer in php etc but here always when I enter I have no reputation to set answer or even vote.