# text comes out of the container when I write long text (without space)

Tags: html, css, overflow

If I write a long sentence the text doesn't fit the container. Why does the text overflow the container?

But when I write a long sentence but use spaces (write more than 1 sentence), the text finally fits the container.

```html
<p>no spaces:</p>
<div style="height:50px;width: 200px;border: 4px solid red;">helloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</div>
<br>
<p>with spaces:</p>
<div style="height:50px;width: 200px;border: 4px solid red; ">hello ooooooo ooooo ooooooo ooooooooo oooooooo</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force a line break in a long word in a DIV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058866/how-to-force-a-line-break-in-a-long-word-in-a-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To break the line of your text you can use `overflow-wrap: break-word;`:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>no spaces:</p>
  <div style="height:50px;width: 200px;border: 4px solid red;overflow-wrap: break-word;">helloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</div>
  <br>
  <p>with spaces:</p>
  <div style="height:50px;width: 200px;border: 4px solid red;
  ">hello ooooooo ooooo ooooooo ooooooooo oooooooo</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Rob Please mark the answer as the accepted one if  It resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below the new styling that I added -> word-wrap: break-word;
This makes the word break and fit the box size.

```html
<p>no spaces:</p>
<div style="height:50px;width: 200px;border: 4px solid red; word-wrap: break-word;">helloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</div>
<br>
<p>with spaces:</p>
<div style="height:50px;width: 200px;border: 4px solid red; ">hello ooooooo ooooo ooooooo ooooooooo oooooooo</div>
```

Comment: worked!!! tysmm

Answer (score 0):

By default, the UserAgent (default stylesheet of the browser) will not randomly break a word into multiple lines. The default setting is `word-break: normal`.

That means that a line-break will only appear on white-spaces, dashes, and [line break opportunities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr) (`<wbr>` tag).

Alternativly, you can allow a browser to break words at any point to fit the container by using: `word-break: break-all`:

```css
div {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>no spaces:</p>
  <div style="height:50px;width: 200px;border: 4px solid red;overflow-wrap: break-word;">helloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</div>
  <br>
  <p>with spaces:</p>
  <div style="height:50px;width: 200px;border: 4px solid red;
  ">hello ooooooo ooooo ooooooo ooooooooo oooooooo</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[MDN Documentation for word-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)