# Discretionary line break in HTML?

Tags: html, control-characters

I'm looking for a way to specify where a line should break ***if*** it cannot fit on its line in a way similar to `&shy;` (soft/discretionary hyphen), but with a space. I tried googling it but didn't get many relevant hits (mostly for InDesign despite specifying "html"), and what I did get was a few people saying they didn't know of a way.

Ex.

> Hello, my name
>   
> is foo.
>   
> **vs.**
>   
> Hello,
>   
> my name is foo.
>   
> **but if space is available:**
>   
> Hello, my name is foo.

For specificity, I do not mean `white-space: normal/nowrap/pre/…` and I don't want to force a break like with `<br />`.

I'm using AngularJS, so most everything is processed thru JavaScript, so if there's an easy/efficient/clever way to do it with that, I'd be open to it.

Comment: Possible help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226464/soft-hyphen-in-html-wbr-vs-shy

Comment: I don't know of a sane way to to this either. An insane way would be to use `&nbsp;` for every space *except* the one you want to break at but that would mess up the entire text. If it's just the *hello* part, though, it just might work.

Comment: What about an invisible `&shy;`?

Comment: @SLaks, that might just be it. I'm thinking: `Hello, &shy;my name is foo.`. I wonder what browsers will do with that. Will test and report. thanks!

Comment: @SLaks it doesn't really work :(

Answer (score 17):

To indicate where line break should *not* appear between words, use a NO-BREAK SPACE, or ' `, between words. Any normal space *is* breakable. So you can write e.g.

```
Hello,&nbsp;my&nbsp;name is&nbsp;foo.
```

If you would rather indicate the allowed breaks (as per your comment below), you can wrap the text inside a `nobr` element (nonstandard, but works like a charm) or inside any element for which you set `white-space: nowrap`, thereby disallowing line breaks except when explicitly forced or allowed. You would then use the `<wbr>` tag (nonstandard, but...) or the character reference `&#8203;` or `&#x200b;` (for ice ZERO WIDTH SPACE) *after* a space to allow a line break, e.g.

```
<nobr>Hello, <wbr>my name <wbr>is foo.</nobr>
```

The choice between `<wbr>` and ZERO WIDTH SPACE is a [tricky issue](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html), mainly due to IE oddities.

Comment: For instance, I would do something like: `Hello,&dbr;my name is foo.` (where `&dbr;` is a discretionary line break, but as far as I know, `&dbr;` is not real).

Comment: @jacob, just don’t use made-up entities. What is the problem?

Comment: I want to specify exactly where a line break should occure IF a line break is required. I would really prefer to use one character to specify where it should occure instead of using a bunch of characters to specify everywhere it shouldn't.

Comment: @jacob, I added an alternate answer that works along such lines, but I think it’s more logical and more robust to use spaces vs. no-break spaces (universally supported). But if the text contains hyphens, then the other approach might be better (because some browsers treat hyphens as allowing a line break after them by default).

Comment: That sounded so promising; alas, it didn't work :( http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/2agtK/

Comment: D’oh, it seems that browsers have largely dropped support to `wbr` and zero width spaces inside `nobr` (Chrome still honors `wbr` inside `nobr`). I think this puts us into square one: divide the text into non-breakable segments.

Comment: Ugh; how as html/css ignore this :(

Comment: The `wbr` does work inside a `nobr` tag, you just can't define width on the nobr tag, you have to define it on the wrapper tag: http://jsfiddle.net/sxc6h7jn/

Answer (score 13):

You could use the [`<wbr>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-wbr-element) tag.

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, you could use a [zero-width space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space): `&#8203;` (See also: [What's the opposite of a nbsp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046530/whats-the-opposite-of-a-nbsp))

Comment: Only for HTML5. Also, try to find resources *other than* w3schools :D

Comment: The [`wbr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/wbr) is for breaking *within* a word. The OP wants to guide the browser to break between the words set.

Comment: @pst - IE has been supporting `wbr` since version 5.5

Comment: @pst - Couldn't agree more about *staying the hell away* from w3schools.

Comment: Ah crap, didn't realise that. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046530/whats-the-opposite-of-a-nbsp then

Comment: The reference to w3chools is crap, but using `wbr` is a practical solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a technique that still works: break text into groups using spans of `inline-block`.

https://jsfiddle.net/mindplay/7aeyp3hs/

[image: example]

Note that I'm using an `@media` rule to turn off this effect on very small devices, where the text will just flow as text normally flows.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any native way to do that, but here's a hack I've been using whenever I really need this sort of thing:

```
var str = "Hello,<br>My name is foo.";

str = str.replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;').replace(/<br>/g, ' ');
```

Basically, use a non-breaking space to separate the words you don't want to break at.

See it here in action: http://jsfiddle.net/5xmt6/ (resize the window to see how it reacts).

---

**Note:** this is *very* hacky, and introduces its own set of problems; namely: if the viewport becomes extremely narrow, the rest of the text won't wrap.

Comment: That is clever, however much of a mess it will make haha. thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @mindplay.dk's answer, I would recommend what I've done in the past with decent result: use `@media` breakpoints applied to `br` tags to control when those line breaks should render (as `display: block`) vs. not (`display: none`).

If you have breakpoints set up for mobile, tablet, and desktop, for example, you can do the following (Bootstrap-like code without needing to specify further CSS, as you can use their `d-[sm|md|lg]` variants):

```html
Hello,<br class="d-none d-lg-block" />
my name is foo.
```