# How can I force text in a new line?

Tags: html, css

I have this div:

```
<div class="text">
    Thisismytextwontgoinanewparagraph
</div>
```

with this CSS:

```
.text
{
    background-color:red;
    width:100px;
}
```

[As you can see in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/esGEn/), the text goes outside of the div.

Is there a way in CSS to force wrapping for a text without spaces (such as a hyperlink)?

Comment: And what does your question have to do with a 'new paragraph'?

Comment: Sorry, dunno how to say in english "new line". Maybe just "new line" ;)

Comment: @DavidThomas: paragraphs are often indicated with a line break.

Comment: You're missing a `<p></p>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the opposite of a nbsp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046530/whats-the-opposite-of-a-nbsp)

Comment: This question has probably been asked dozens of times at SO, mostly with wrong answers (like here). I’ve suggested that this be marked  as a duplicate of a question that has reasonable answers, even though the question title is a bit obscure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could try this, but it's not very pretty:

```
.text
{
    background-color:red;
    width:100px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/esGEn/1/

Comment: The code breaks the string at arbitrary points. This is seldom acceptable, and surely not for URLs (which is what the question probably means by “such as a hyperlink”).

Comment: thus, " but it's not very pretty"

Comment: You can make certain elements unbreakable with `white-space:nowrap`, like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/keaukraine/JsNgQ/

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use ellipsis with overflow hidden? That will also look pretty.

```
.text {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I did it. I added the `<br>` tag to the text I wanted to push to the next line.
`<p> Sleek custom designs and durable functionality. <br>Let your headwear work for you. </p>`
[text multiple lines example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3PUz.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).