# Non breaking lengthy word

Tags: html, css

Please dont mind for adding a vulnarable content as below.

jffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj

I have a multiline html text editor(tiny mce). When a user enters unappropriate words, as i entered above!. It will be saved properly in database. When i am trying to display the same data using a label. The displayed data disturbs the page design.

How can i fix this issue?
Please provide me a solution for this.

Thanks in advance
Regards,
Madhu BN

Comment: +1 for overrunning the SO layout. Obviously they didn't use any of the answers here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I found another way to achieve this without using overflow: hidden property.

Simply by making use of 
<div style="word-wrap: break-word; width: 500px;">

Thanks once again guys.

Comment: I had included `break-work` as an edit to my answer too.

Comment: Sorry i was not yet refreshed the page. Yes, you are perfect. 

I am trying to put the width as 100%. At that time word wrap is going out of my parent div whose width is 100% too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's about disturbing the page design when redisplaying the user's input and if the input is "inappropriate" then apply a CSS style to cut it off by using [overflow:hidden](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp).

```
<style> 
    .fixed { overflow:hidden; }
</style>
```

Then apply it to the div or container:

```
<div class="fixed" style="width:100px">The following input is really long and invalid. 

fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj

jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj</div>
```

This ensures the page layout is not disturbed. In the above example 100px is adhered to no matter the unbreaking length of the invalid text.

### Edits:

If you want the wrapping behaviour try using CSS [word-wrap: break-word;](http://www.css3.com/css-word-wrap/)

```
<style>
.fixed {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
</style>
```

Or even put them both together to be really safe across browsers.

```
<style> 
    .fixed { 
        overflow:hidden; 
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I agree... this is definitely the most reliable way to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.
Without hiding the text, cant we break the content to move to next line.

It works fine if i am making use of width in terms of pixel. What can i do if i am using %.

Comment: I made an edit to show another option. Styles should exhibit the same behaviour whether you're using a pixel width like `width:100px` or a percentage like `width:90%`

Answer (score 1):

If you use PHP to print out the text, check out the [wordwrap](http://php.net/wordwrap) function.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the programming technology. I am using c# with asp.net

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting `&shy;` into the string. It's the HTML element for the "[soft hyphen](http://www.google.ca/search?q=html+soft+hyphen)".

If using PHP, `print(wordwrap($string, 75, '&shy;'));`

More info on SO: [Soft hyphen in HTML (<wbr> vs. &shy;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226464/soft-hyphen-in-html-wbr-vs-shy)

Comment: As far as I know this isn't cross browser: http://gojomo.blogspot.com/2005/03/cross-browser-invisible-word-break-in.html

Comment: That's the impression I got from the linked SO question. Probably should've opened with that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a crossbrowser solution that I was looking at a little while ago that runs on the client and using jQuery:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.breakWords = function() {
    this.each(function() {
      if(this.nodeType !== 1) { return; }

      if(this.currentStyle && typeof this.currentStyle.wordBreak === 'string') {
        //Lazy Function Definition Pattern, Peter's Blog
        //From http://peter.michaux.ca/article/3556
        this.runtimeStyle.wordBreak = 'break-all';
      }
      else if(document.createTreeWalker) {

        //Faster Trim in Javascript, Flagrant Badassery
        //http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript

        var trim = function(str) {
          str = str.replace(/^\s\s*/, '');
          var ws = /\s/,
          i = str.length;
          while (ws.test(str.charAt(--i)));
          return str.slice(0, i + 1);
        };

        //Lazy Function Definition Pattern, Peter's Blog
        //From http://peter.michaux.ca/article/3556

        //For Opera, Safari, and Firefox
        var dWalker = document.createTreeWalker(this, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, false);
        var node,s,c = String.fromCharCode('8203');
        while (dWalker.nextNode()) {
          node = dWalker.currentNode;
          //we need to trim String otherwise Firefox will display
          //incorect text-indent with space characters
          s = trim( node.nodeValue ).split('').join(c);
          node.nodeValue = s;
        }
      }
    });

    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, add \u200b - Zero Width Space before displaying it

```
YOURTEXT=YOURTEXT.replace(/(.)/g,"\u200b$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use InsertAt repeatedly to achieve @Ryan's solution, or you could perform validation to prevent such malformed data from reaching the database.

Regular expressions would also make this available to put the soft-hyphen in.

Answer (score 0):

It can be fixed with a little CSS using [overflow-x (lots of cool examples after link)](http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html).

Just make sure you specify a width, otherwise overflow-x won't do you any good.

**Try it [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/42655/eternity/overflow-width.html)**

```
<style>
div{
  width: 105px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 4px;
  background: orange;
}
</style>
<div>WAYTOOLONGTOBESHOWN</div>
<div>WAYTOOLONGTOBESHOWN</div>
```