# display/make soft hyphen visible in html

Tags: html, soft-hyphen

The font I'm using have soft hyphen as a very common character in my written language and I'm required to use it for many reasons, but html for various reason I have read make them invisible which make word that have the character hard and awkward to read and understand (think "road" display as "rad" or "rod"). is there anyway, using html, css or whatever there is to force soft hyphen visible on website?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Soft hyphen in HTML (<wbr> vs. &shy;)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226464/soft-hyphen-in-html-wbr-vs-shy)

Comment: Which “soft hyphen” are you talking about? How do fonts relate to the issue? The Unicode SOFT HYPHEN U+00AD is by definition an invisible control character; if you want something visible, use something else. It would help if you mentioned the language and gave some concrete examples.

Comment: the language Vietnamese and the font is .VnTimes, the character "ư" of that font is mapped to to U+00AD, I need to make it visible because many word contain it, the sentence "đoạn đường này dài 10km" would become "đoạn đờng này dài 10km" which would be somewhat like "this road is 10km long" become "this rod is 10 km long", and as I already mentioned due to requirements I can't just use font that have the character "ư" mapped to something that is normally visible.

Comment: the character display normally with that .VnTimes font on MS Word and Notepad btw.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of 226464 - they want a way to tell the browser to treat 0xAD as a printable character, not as &shy;.