# How to give a break line at max-width point?

Tags: jquery, css

Dynamically, my code receive some variables and join them with an underscore:

```
var text = product + "_" + someOtherInfo;
```

And I need to show this text inside a div.

```
div {
    max-width: 200px;
    /* ... */
}
```

---

The problem is occurring when the text gets more than 200px. I did a [fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/skjpnzkh/)

The number of lines isn't a problem... So, I want to give a break line at max-width point.

Is it possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried soft hyphens? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226464/soft-hyphen-in-html-wbr-vs-shy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

Add this in your div style

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/skjpnzkh/1/)**