# How to put dash at the break point of word?

Tags: css, word-break

When i have long word which is longer than my container i am using "word-break: break-all;". I was wondering is it possible to put dash(-) at the break point of the word?

This is the css that i am using for the text:

```
p{    
-ms-word-break: break-all;
 word-break: break-all;

-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/L18c813r/1/

Comment: Your code is correct (bar missing some prefixed properties) but not all browsers, most notably Chrome, fully support hyphenation yet. You can check the  browser support for `hyphens` [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-hyphens) and for `word-break` [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=word-break).

Comment: Star this chromium issue and comment on it if you like to use hyphens:auto crossbrowser:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47083

Answer (score 0):

You need the full set:

```
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
   -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
        hyphens: auto;
```

The issue is there isn't full browser support for them. Test in IE, Firefox, or Safari.

There's a javascript library you can use to remedy that though. It's called Hypenator. http://mnater.github.io/Hyphenator/

Comment: I am not sure about this  " hyphens". I don't see any difference with or without it in chrome or firefox. Maybe i don't use it right.

Comment: Well if you didn't use webkit you don't see it in Firefox. Chrome doesn't support hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use `&shy;` in the word where it *could* wrap.

For this method, you need to specify possible "to-long-words" and add the html-tag manually.

[also see this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/227284/2961798)

Comment: The problem is that i don't know the exact position of the break.

Comment: I see. But do you really want any word wrapped at any letter? Wouldn't it be better to use something like `text-align:justify;` to make sure your text is always wrapped at the same length?