# Improving Text Justification in CSS

Tags: css, text-align, justify

I'm working on some mobile content which has loads of text in numerous pages.

I gave them the property `text-align: justify;` which usually works well and hence makes the text become much more readable and good-looking.

Although in some situations, the justifications sucks since it leads to unnecessary spaces between words.

[image]

How can I improve this styling so that it performs better in various situations?

Comment: There is a thing called `hyphens` in CSS3, if you'd like to give that a try.

Comment: Put a soft hyphen (`&shy;`) in long words.

Answer (score 0):

- Reduce `font-size` and/or `letter-spacing` so more words can stretch better on the same line
- Use optional breaks (`<wbr>`, `&shy;`) inside long words

Apart from the above you can write some JS-CSS that do a custom streching but you can't really change the rules of geometry and the default one is quite close to optimal.

Comment: I doubt if he wants `<wbr>`. That would randomly break lines there in the middle of the word with no hyphen.

Comment: edited to match http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226464/soft-hyphen-in-html-wbr-vs-shy