# Can words be broken at 50% with word-break:break-all

Tags: css

Can I break words only at 50% using css? Is it possible?

Instead of 
`longwor
d`

doesn't `long
word` look better?

What's the alternative?

Update: So maybe we can auto `<wbr>` with js on the really long words.

Comment: So, you want your browser to understand where is the "50%" of the word? If there is a word "stackoverflow", do you want it to output "stack overflow" or "stackov erflow"?

Comment: Anything is fine as long as it is not stackoverfl ow or st ackoverflow since it doesn't look good. Middle(closest) is fine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226464/soft-hyphen-in-html-wbr-vs-shy

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32778297/5305938

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CSS [`hyphens: auto`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-text-20110412/#hyphens) allows for automatic language-aware sensible hyphenation. Language is derived from the `lang` property.

Compatibility varies with language and browser  (not implemented at all in Chrome, sadly).

You may also find use for `&shy;` which is a manual hyphenation clue. It is called a *soft hyphen* and is not visibly rendered, but merely suggests to the browser where a word may be broken.

[Css tricks has a good writeup on the subject](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hyphenate/)

**Edit**

As per your request in comments, I've made slight alterations to Resig's snippet, so that the pattern targets the full word and inserts the `<wbr>` in the calculated middle, rather than always after the treshold length.

The only modification to the actual pattern is to continue the search, and not stop after the threshold. I've also done away with the grouping brackets, as we'll only be using the full word:

```
RegExp("\\w{" + num + "}\\w+", "g")
```

We then find the center of the word (`c = Math.floor(all.length/2)`) and insert a browser hint at that point. I added a parameter to indicate whether `wbr` or `shy` should be used. The latter renders as a hyphen when hyphenation is required, and the former does not.

```
all.substring(0,c) + (!!shy?'&shy;':'<wbr>') + all.substring(c)
```

Note that for word lengths greater than `num*2`, the individual parts will also exceed the treshold. To get around this, I've simply added recursion:

```
function wbr(str, num, shy) {  
  return str.replace(RegExp("\\w{" + num + "}\\w+", "g"), function(all){
    var c = Math.floor(all.length/2);
    return wbr(all.substring(0,c) + (!!shy?'&shy;':'<wbr>') + all.substring(c),num,shy);
  });
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9a65mnvb/)

Comment: So maybe we can auto <wbr> with js on the really long words.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable workaround. `&shy;` appears to be compatible across all major browser; don't know about `<wbr>`. [There's still activity on the chromium ticket](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47083) so that may be cause for expecting it to be implemented, even though the ticket itself is 5 years old.

Comment: Found something useful http://ejohn.org/blog/injecting-word-breaks-with-javascript/

Comment: Hyphenator, frmo Jacques' answer, is the library mentioned in the bottom of the post you've linked. If you're going for the very simple solution that John provides, you'll still be breaking at inappropriate places. From his own example: `writin<wbr>g`. I can't really see that you've won anything over `break-all`.

Comment: Agree, hence may be I will try to find the words longer than 7 letters and break them in the middle with &shy or wbr. Do you have a script that does that... I am not exp. with js.

Comment: So cool... Thanks :) In fact the adv. of `<wbr>` is it adds the hyphen as well

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [Hyphenator](https://github.com/mnater/hyphenator) library, as the `hyphens: auto` CSS property is [not supported in the Chrome and Android Browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-hyphens).

To use this library follow these simple steps:

- Download the recent version of Hyphenator.js
- Add `hyphenate` classes to the elements, set `lang` and add the Hyphenator.js `<script>`.

Comment: Its a huge 142KB library :(