# &shy; How to get rid of the extra hyphen at the end of word

Tags: html

I have a word that I have put a `&shy;` inside. It hyphens alright until I get to a small enough screen size then it adds an extra hyphen at the end.

Edit: Can't reproduce it in jsfiddle, because it seems to interpret the html differently. I can show a picture of the problem however

```
<h3>
Flu&shy;ffyluffy Some&shy;something</h3>
```

Becomes

[image]

With an extra hyphen at the end

I saw this and didn't really like the answer, [Extra hyphen at end of word if &shy; is used in middle of the word and the parent div is narrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32840131/extra-hyphen-at-end-of-word-if-shy-is-used-in-middle-of-the-word-and-the-paren). "just make the div wider".

Are there any ways to make it not add extra hyphens I didn't ask for instead?

Writing

```
<h3 class="something">Something Something&shy;Something</h3>



<style>
.something{
 width:85px
}
<\style>
```

On http://htmledit.squarefree.com/

Causes a similar issue but not quite. I can only seem to replicate with Chrome

Comment: Please  reproduce the problem at jsfiddle, it will be easier to help you, Cheers

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue in js fiddle but I've added a picture to better explain what my problem is.

Comment: That sounds much like a browser bug, not something you can do anything about. What browser (version) are you using, does it happen with others as well?

Comment: Chrome 51.0.2704.103 and it's only an issue I've seen in chrome

Comment: I was able to reproduce it in chrome on a fiddle with a screen size of 530px, the hypens appears like the image you've posted.

Comment: Could you post a link to where you replicated it? That would be cool :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use flex?

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZxBgJ)

**HTML**

It seems to work in chrome for me if I add `display: inline-flex;`

```
<h3 class="something">
  Flu&shy;ffyluffy Some&shy;something
</h3>
```

**CSS**

```
.something{
 width:60px;
 display: inline-flex;
}
```

Comment: Ohh it seems to have broken it on Safari though :-/

Comment: I guess there's no fix that works for everything because setting display: inline-flex; didn't seem to fix it on Safari (I hadn't noticed it wasn't working on Safari), and it broke something else for me.