# Text inside of <li> tag goes out of screen

Tags: html, css

I have some long text in a `<li>` tag and it goes out of screen when the screen is narrow.

I've tried to correct this with `width: 100%;` but nothing happens. Additionally, the text should not have a fixed width, it must be responsive.

This is my code structure:

```
<div class="absolute-pos inline-block">
  <li>
      <div>
      <span>
          some really really loooonnnnggg teeeeeexxxxttttt hheeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeerrrreeeee
      </span>
      </div>
  </li>
</div>

.absolute-pos {
  position: absolute;
}
.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xLm5hL3w/

Comment: I know, but it must be there, this is only a part of my layout.

Comment: Add the CSS rule: `word-break: break-word;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have several options. Here are the first that come to my mind:

The first is `width:100%; overflow:hidden;`. This will "clip" any text that goes beyond the edge of the page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

The second is `word-break:break-all;`. This allows your text to wrap onto a new line between any two letters.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

The third -- and what I would recommend -- is the `<wbr>` tag. This tells the browser where it's "allowed" to put breaks in long words. If there's no need to break the words then it won't, unlike `<br>` or a space character.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr

The fourth is the `text-overflow` property. This gives you more nuanced control over how your text appears when it's too long, but won't affect wrapping.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

The fifth is the `&shy;` special character. This tells the browser that it can break a word and wrap it to the next line using a hyphen. Like `<wbr>`, this is applied only when necessary.

[Soft hyphen in HTML (<wbr> vs. &shy;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226464/soft-hyphen-in-html-wbr-vs-shy)

The sixth is `word-wrap:break-word;`. This tells the browser that it can break long words between any two letters. This is a better choice than `word-break` because that tells the browser to break between any two letters without being limited to long words. (The fact that these two are separate things drives me bonkers.)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap

Comment: Add `word-wrap` and `white-space` to your list.

Comment: Thanks! I've added `word-wrap`. I don't think `white-space` would be useful here since it could only be used if they were to put breaks/spaces in his long words, which it seems they wish to avoid.