# Is there a way to put an hyphen when <wbr> occurs?

Tags: html

I have a really big word that is just too long for mobile views, I can break it with `<wbr>` but the rules of this language require an hyphen when a word is separate on two pieces.

Is there a way to say:

```
thisreally<wbr>longword
```

must be

```
thisreally-
longword
```

when cutted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Soft hyphen in HTML (<wbr> vs. &shy;)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226464/soft-hyphen-in-html-wbr-vs-shy)

Comment: Could be, but I wasn't aware of the existence of  `&shy`, while the other question ask about the difference between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `&shy;` instead:

```html
thisareallyreallyreallyreallyreallyreally&shy;andverylongwordwithashynewline
```

> The `<wbr>` element doesn't support a new line character like `-`.
>   You can find more information about this here: http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html

Comment: I did not it! it does the work without any special css. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try It Once Its Working Fine

```css
a:before {
   content:" - ";
}
```

```html
<a href="#">CSS-Tricks</a>
```

Comment: No, that doesn't get rendered.

Comment: Now Check In My Snippet